# address of array ptr equal to to it's value?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, printf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C: How come an array’s address is equal to its value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/c-how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value)

SA 
In C I tried to print the address of the pointer of an array.

```
int a[3] = {0,1,2};
printf("\n%p",a);
printf("\n%p",(&a));
```

the 2 statement prints the same value why?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any array argument to a function will decay to a pointer to the first element of the array.

[The C Book](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter5/arrays_and_address_of.html) has an excellent explanation of this:

> Another case is when an array name is
>   the operand of the & address-of
>   operator. Here, it is converted into
>   the address of the whole array. What's
>   the difference? Even if you think that
>   addresses would be in some way ‘the
>   same’, the critical difference is that
>   they have different types. For an
>   array of n elements of type T, then
>   the address of the first element has
>   type ‘pointer to T’; the address of
>   the whole array has type ‘pointer to
>   array of n elements of type T’;
>   clearly very different

Answer (score 0):

In C arrays "decay" to pointers to their first element in certain contexts. Passing an array to a function is one of these cases.

Answer (score 0):

Because local arrays are treated as a special case (they decay to pointers).

In your case &a is translated to a.

If you try with an int pointer, e.g.,

```
int c = 3;    
int* p = &c;
```

you should get different values.

Answer (score 0):

An array "decays" into a pointer to it's elements in some situations.  Passing it as an argument to a function is one of those.  Thus in

```
void func(int * pi, size_t nints);
int a[3] = {0, 1, 2};
func(a, 3);
```

the pointer to `a` is passed to `func`.  This is what happens in your code as well. This also happens when you assign it to a pointer:

```
int * pi = a;
assert(*pi == 0); assert(*(pi + 1) == 1); assert(*(pi + 2) == 2);
```

The asserts here would also work if you replace `pi` with `a`.