# array addressing

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C: How come an array's address is equal to its value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/c-how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
  int a[3];
  printf("%p %p",&a,a);
  return 0; 
 }
```

the output for this program shows the same value for a and &a. I'm confused. Enlighten me.