# Using memcpy with array name

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C: How come an array's address is equal to its value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/c-how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value)

I recently found code in my project that calls `memcpy` with the address of array name

```
int a[10];
memcpy(&a, &b ,sizeof(a));
```

Surprisingly (to me) it seems to work.

Should I change it to `memcpy(a,b,sizeof(a));` ?

Is it allowed by the C++ spec? 
Can anyone point me to resource about this behavior? Are there any pitfalls?

I also checked

```
assert((void*)&a == (void*)a);
```

and `&a` indeed is the same as `a` (besides it's type).

I verified this behavior in VS2005, VS2008 and VS2010.

Answer (score 4):

`&a` is the address of the array; `a` can be implicitly converted to the address of the first element. Both have the same address, and so both will give the same value when converted to `void*`.

> Are there any pitfalls?

`memcpy` is not typesafe, so it's quite easy to write code that compiles but behaves badly; for example, if `a` were a pointer rather than an array, then `sizeof a` would compile but give the wrong value. C++'s typesafe templates can protect against that:

```
std::copy(b, std::end(b), a); // will only compile if `b` has a known end.
```

Answer (score 2):

The name of an array evaluates to the address of the beginning of the array, so the two have identical meaning. See [How come an array's address is equal to its value in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/c-how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value) (it's a C question but the same holds for C++).

Comment: Yeah, the post you've linked gives great answer.

Answer (score 1):

Like you say, it doesn't matter.

When passed as a parameter, the name of the array will "decay" into a pointer to its first element.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the address of an array is the same as the address of its first element.
So there's no need to change the `memcpy` call. Unless you're afraid that the definition of the array might change to a pointer later (like `int* a = new int[10];`).

Of course, if you're going to make changes to the program anyway, it might be best to dispense with the whole `memcpy` and use real C++ instead.