# Using memcpy to convert betweencomplex< double>* to fftw_complex*

Tags: c++, visual-c++, fftw

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [memcpy(), what should the value of the size parameter be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681061/memcpy-what-should-the-value-of-the-size-parameter-be)

I want to copy a dynamic array:

```
g  = new complex<double> [N*N];
```

to `in` of type `fftw_complex*`:

```
in = (fftw_complex*) fftw_alloc_complex(N*N);
```

When I use:

```
in= (fftw_complex*) fftw_alloc_complex(N*N);
memcpy( in , g , sizeof(g));
out = (fftw_complex*) fftw_alloc_complex(N*N);
my_plan = fftw_plan_dft_2d(N,N, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
fftw_execute(my_plan);
fftw_destroy_plan(my_plan);
fftw_free(in);
fftw_free(out);
```

I get weird results. Just zeros for both in and out.

Strangely, when I use instead:

```
memcpy( &in , &g , sizeof(g));
```

I get exactly the correct results, but with this the line:

```
fftw_free(in);
```

...does not work. It gives "unhandled exception" error.

Comment: This doesn't sound right.  Please construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).  (Also note that as you've found that `in` is wrong, you may as well eliminate everything after the `memcpy`, as it's irrelevant.)

Comment: do you have the source code of fftw_free and fftw_alloc_complex? I think these methods do more than a simple alloc and free, that's what might cause the problem

Comment: Why don't you think of designing your class fftw_complex copy-construcetd from complex<T>?

Comment: sizeof pointer is always the same, 4 or 8, depending on the platform. perhaps you want to say `N*N*sizeof(complex<double>)`.

Comment: @MariusBancila - that's an answer, not a comment. In fact, it is the correct answer.

Comment: @Robᵩ, Marius: In which case, I'd arguably close this as "too localized" or as a suitable duplicate.  We probably don't need the millionth question whose answer is "you're using sizeof incorrectly"!

Comment: Marius, I tried what you said and indeed it gave me a different answer but not the correct one :(. I saw here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681932/using-memcpy-with-array-name that there is a problem using memcpy with pointers, so I'm trying to figure out how to use it .