# ways to refer to an array

Tags: c++, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C: How come an array’s address is equal to its value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/c-how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value)

Could someone maybe help me explain array decaying? In specific, I was confused about 1) how does an array refer to itself, and 2) is it true that, when I define

```
int array[] = { 45, 67, 89 };
```

then array, &array,and &array[0] all refer to this array? I found out they appear as the same outputs when printed, but are they also referring to exactly the same thing in memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array`, in value contexts is a of type `int *`, and the pointer points to the first element of the array. `&array`, is of type "pointer to an array [3] of `int`" and points to the whole `array`.  `&array[0]` is of type `int *`, and points to the first element of the array.

So, `&array[0]` is the same as `array`, *if `array` is used in value context*.  One situation where `array` is not used in value context is in `sizeof` operator.  So: `sizeof array` will be different from `sizeof &array[0]`.

Let's take an example:

```
int array[] = { 45, 67, 89 };
int *pa = array; /* pa is now pointing to the first element of "array" */
int *pb = &array[0]; /* pb is also pointing to the same */
int (*pc)[3] = &array; /* pc points to the whole array.
                          Note the type is not "int *" */

printf("%zu\n", sizeof &array[0]); /* prints size of an "int *" */
printf("%zu\n", sizeof array); /* prints 3 times the size of an int */
printf("%zu\n", sizeof &array); /* prints size of pointer to an array[3] of int */
```

See also: http://web.torek.net/torek/c/pa.html

Answer (score 8):

> then array, &array,and &array[0] all refer to this array?

The memory location will be the same, but the types will be different.

- `array` is just that: an array of 3 integers
- `&array` has type `int (*)[3]`, a pointer to an array
- `&array[0]` has type `int *`, a pointer to a single integer

Answer (score 0):

They all refer to same memory location but little differently. `array` and `&array` refer the entire array starting with the address of first element, while `&array[0]` refers the first element only in the array.