# Memory address in C

Tags: c, c-strings, dynamic-allocation

In the last line of the main function, why does `&word2` differ from `word2`? Assume the right headers are in place. Thank you!

```
int main()
{
    char word1[20];
    char *word2;

    word2 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);

    printf("Sizeof word 1: %d\n", sizeof (word1));
    printf("Sizeof word 2: %d\n", sizeof (word2));

    strcpy(word1, "string number 1");
    strcpy(word2, "string number 2");

    printf("%s\n", word1);
    printf("%s\n", word2);
    printf("Address %d, evaluated expression: %d\n", &word1, word1);
    printf("Address %d, evaluated expression: %d\n", &word2, word2); 
    //Why this one differ?
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`word2` is the address of the memory that you allocated using `malloc`.

`&word2` is the address of the variable named `word2`.

Comment: Bah - 15 seconds too slow.  :)

Answer (score 2):

The first is the address on the stack of the `word2` pointer - a double pointer where the value is stored.

The second is the actual address stored within `word2` - somewhere on the heap I would presume from the malloc.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare `char word1[20];`  creates an array of 20 chars. Here, `word1` is the address of its first element but not of the array.

`& word1` means address of array. The values of  `word1` and `&word1` are really the same, but semantically both are different. One is an address of a char, while the other is an address of an array of 20 chars. [you should read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189967/issue-with-pointer-to-character-array-c/14192945#14192945).

second case:

when you declare  `char *word2;` you creates a pointer variable. it can point to a char or can store address of dynamically allocated array like you did.

so value of `word2` means address return by `malloc()`. in below line.

```
word2 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
```

but expression `&word2` means address of pointer variable. and address return by malloc is different then address of pointer veritable `word2`.

`word2` is not same as `word1` type.

read also [Nate Chandler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189967/issue-with-pointer-to-character-array-c?answertab=votes#tab-top)

The fundamental difference between `word1`  and `word2`:

In below diagram.

[image: diagram]

`word1` is same as `a` (*not by size but by type*).  and `word2` is like `p`

here value of `p` means address of `"world"` string and `&p` means address of `p` variable.

Answer (score 0):

In the first statement `&word1` refers to the address of the array. Since this array is statically allocated on stack `&word1` is same as `word1` which is same as `&word1[0]`.

In the second case `word2`is pointer on stack whose address is shown in first part of print and `word2` contains the pointer which is allocated through `malloc`.