# Why is localarr==&localarr?

Tags: c, arrays, local, callstack, memory-address

I mean, why does this print equal numbers to the console?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char localarr[99];
    printf("%d\n",(int)localarr);
    printf("%d\n",(int)&localarr);
    return 0;
}
```

I understand that the address of localarr is not actually stored in any variable. But the generated code could store that behind the scenes, or at least gcc could give warning instead of allowing for segfault when I pass such to a function that expects char**.
Why do we have this behaviour?

Related: why does

```
char **ppl = &localarr;
```

results in:

```
error: cannot convert ‘char (*)[99]’ to ‘char**’
```

?

Comment: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryvsadr.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No,  `localarr` is not same as  `&localarr`

- `localarr` is address of first element but `&localarr` is address of array of chars of size 99. off-course values are same but both are different semantically.
- `localarr` is of type `char [99]`  whereas `&localarr` is of type `char (*)[99]`

And because type of `&localarr` is `char(*)[99]` you should create pointer to array, like:

```
char(*ppl)[99] = &localarr;
```

where `ppl` is ponter to array of chars of size 99

To visualize difference between `localarr` and   `&localarr` below is my diagram:

```
    +----+----+----+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+ 
    | '1'| '2' |'3'|...............  |98  | 99 |  ...........
    +----+----+----+---+---+----+----+----+----+---+----+  
     201   202  203 ...............   210  299
      ^     ^                                         
      |     |                                         
 (localarr) (localarr + 1)                                         
    |                                         |
    |-----------------------------------------|--------
    |201                                      | 299    // 299 -201 = 98
      ^                                          ^
      |                                          |
    (&localarr)                                 (&localarr + 1)
```

(Note:)
*  `localarr + 1` increment by one char size, where as `(&localarr + 1)` increment by `99` array size.

have a look on this code and its output:

```
int main()
{
    char localarr[99] = {'A'};
    printf("%p %p\n",localarr, &localarr);
    printf("%p %p\n",(localarr + 1), (&localarr + 1));
    printf("%c %p  %c\n",*localarr, *&localarr, **&localarr);
        return 0;
}
```

Output:(*read comments*)

```
~$ ./a.out 
0x7fff41ad64b0 0x7fff41ad64b0    // same 
0x7fff41ad64b1 0x7fff41ad6513    // difference is 98, 4b1 + 62 = 513
A      0x7fff41ad64b0  A
```

Note: value of `localarr` and  `&localarr` are same that is `0x7fff41ad64b0`
But values of `*localarr` and  `*&localarr` are not same:

- `*localarr`  is first element
- `*&localarr` is address of first element  `**&localarr` is first element
- that means `*localarr`  is same as `**&localarr` that is first element `localarr[0]`
- Note `0x7fff41ad6513 -  0x7fff41ad64b1 = 0x62` and 0x62 = 98 in decimal

What compiler error message is:

```
error: cannot convert ‘char (*)[99]’ to ‘char**’ 
                       ^                  ^ type of ppl  
                  type of &localarr
```

Read this [Issue with pointer to character array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189967/issue-with-pointer-to-character-array-c/14192945#14192945)

Comment: Although I accepted the answer, I must note that all answers (even for other similar questions) only explain WHAT happens, but NOT WHY it happens. So why is the semantics of C such? It would be less error-prone to just raise a compiler-error and enforce casting. Or not?

Comment: @user1358 C is comparatively low language then other. As I says both are different in types and semantic compiler produces an error. If you compiles with proper option it will produce an warning to.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char localarr[99];
    printf("%d\n",(int)localarr);
    printf("%d\n",(int)&localarr);
    return 0;
}
```

The type of `localarr` is array of 99 `char`.  The type of `&localarr` is pointer to an array of 99 `char`.  The types are different.  However, `localarr` degenerates to a pointer to the first byte of the array.  You can spot the difference most clearly by adding 1 to the addresses (and converting the code to handle the types more reliably — on a 64-bit system, the cast to `int` truncates the pointer):

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char localarr[99];
    printf("0x%08" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)( localarr+0));
    printf("0x%08" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)(&localarr+0));
    printf("0x%08" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)( localarr+1));
    printf("0x%08" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)(&localarr+1));
    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
0x7FFF6D12C4E0
0x7FFF6D12C4E0
0x7FFF6D12C4E1
0x7FFF6D12C543
```

You also ask:

> Why does
>
> ```
>  char **ppl = &localarr;
> ```
>
> result in the error `cannot convert 'char (*)[99]' to 'char**'`?

As already stated, the type of `&localarr` is a pointer to an array of 99 `char`; this type is neither the same as nor convertible to `char **`, which in many ways simply echoes what the error message says.  The types are just completely incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

your statement will work if u use

char *localarr=calloc(99,sizeof(char));

now assigning the address of localarr to a char ** type should work