# Why does my C compiler give a warning?

Tags: c, string, gcc

Beginner question.  I have the following code:

```
char input[10];   
scanf("%s", &input);
```

My compiler throws the following warning:

```
warning: format '%s' expects type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[10]'
warning: format '%s' expects type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[10]'
```

Changing to:

```
char * input;
```

Does not seem to help.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the token `input` is already a `char *`, you are passing a `char **`

Comment: Used in this context, the char array "decays" into a pointer to it's first element, so to a pointer to the stack allocated char array.

Comment: Don't do this. You'll run into buffer overflows quickly. Use `scanf("%9s", input);`.

Comment: Also read [Smashing the stack for fun and profit](http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs161/fa08/papers/stack_smashing.pdf).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because an array already can be used as a pointer, so you don't need to the address-of operator.

If you read the warning message again, you will see that when you use the address-of operator on the array, you get a pointer to the array.

Answer (score 5):

Try,

```
char input[10];   
scanf("%s", input);
```

You don't have to give the **address-of** operator (`&`) with the name of the array `input`.

Comment: you could include about the types of &input and input

Comment: Alternatively, one could use `&input[0]`, but `input` is practically equivalent and faster to type.

Answer (score 1):

`%s` format string accepts argument of type `char*` where as `&intput` is of type `char (*)[10]` that is the reason you are getting warning.

```
format '%s' expects type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[10]
```

Note argument `2` is `&input` in `scanf()`

```
scanf("%s", &input);
       ^       ^ 
       |       argument-2 
       argument-1
```

To correct this code you should write scanf like:

```
scanf("%s", input);
```

**Side note:**:  value wise both `&input` and `input` are same if you string address but semantically both are diffrent.

`&input` is address of array that is `char(*) [10]` type whereas `input`  type  is `char[10]`

To understand difference between `&input` and `input` read this two answers:

1. [What does sizeof(&arr) returns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarr-returns/15177499#15177499) , and
2. [Issue with pointer to character array C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189967/issue-with-pointer-to-character-array-c/14192945#14192945)

**Edit:**

Changing to:  `char *input` will not help you instead it becomes undefined behavoiur unless and until you allocated memory to `input`

Comment: `input` is `char[10]` type actually. it can decay to `char*`.

Comment: scanf typo!! please change.:)

Answer (score 0):

`char input[10]` is a character array.
`input` itself represents the base address of the array, i.e a `char *`.
 **You do not need to use the *address of* operator (`&`)with it**. instead, use:

```
char input[10];   
scanf("%s", input);
```

If you use `char * input;`, you need to allocate space for it using `malloc`. But in this case also, no need to use the ***address of*** operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%s", input);
```

you will get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
char input[10];   
scanf("%s", &input);
```

[`scanf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fscanf.html) requires the address to store the data that will be recieved. Array names already act like pointers, So you don't need the `&` operator to obtain the address.

```
format '%s' expects type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[10]'
```

When you do `&input` it indicates a pointer that is pointing to a char array of 10 char. `char (*)[10]`

`input` is itself `char*` and is only necessary to be passed as 2nd argument to scanf.

Go through [this](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm) too for arrays and pointers.