# C++: When using memcpy, what is the difference between myArray and &myArray?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference, memcpy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How come an array’s address is equal to its value in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c)

In the situation:

```
int x = 5;
unsigned char myArray[sizeof (int)];
```

This line...

```
memcpy (&myArray , &x , sizeof (int));
```

... is producing identical results to:

```
memcpy (myArray , &x , sizeof (int));
```

I am very much a novice to C++, but I was under the impression that arrays are just a pointer to their data.  I was shocked when &myArray was working identical to myArray.  I would have thought it would be trying to copy to the ADDRESS of the pointer, which would be very bad!

Comment: [Arrays are not pointers.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c)

Comment: @Pubby So myArray is identical to &myArray?  There is no 'catch'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things about arrays:

- Arrays "decay" to pointers of their element type. This is why the second version is working. See this :[Is an array name a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c)
- There is such a thing as a "pointer to array". They are rarely used, but look like this:

---

```
int a[5];
int (*b)[5] = &a; // pointer to an array of 5 ints
```

The `&` operator when used on an array gives you a pointer to array type, which is why the following doesn't work:

```
int* b = &a; // error
```

Since `memcpy`'s parameter is a `void*`, which accepts any pointer type, both `&myArray` and `myArray` work. I'll recommend going with `myArray` though as it's more idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in believing the types are different. `&myArray` is a `unsigned char(*)[]` (a pointer to an array of unsigned char) and `myArray` (when passed to a function as an argument) becomes type `unsigned char*` (pointer to unsigned char). However, note that even though the types are different, there value is the **same address**. The reason both work with memcpy is because `memcpy` takes `void*` and doesn't care about the type.

Answer (score 1):

> what is the difference between myArray and &myArray?

They both point to the first element of myArray.

The name of an array usually evaluates to the address of the first element of the array, so myArray and &myArray have the same value.

[memcpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) function takes memory address to destination as input argument. As myArray and &myArray points to the same place, so the effort is the same:

```
void* memcpy( void* dest, const void* src, std::size_t count );

Parameters
dest   -     pointer to the memory location to copy to
src    -     pointer to the memory location to copy from
count  -     number of bytes to copy
```

Comment: There is a huge difference, as you can see if you display sizeof (myArray) and sizeof (&myArray).