# how a pointer to pointer is able to refer the array

Tags: c++, syntax

```
#include<cstdio>
int main() {

int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

int *ptr = (int*)(&a+1);

printf("%d %d" ,*(a+1),*(ptr-1));
}
```

here there the address location of a+1 is typecasted to point ptr;

i have tried *ptr = (int*)&a it is pointing the array..
as pointer address is stored in some location pointer ptr is pointing to that location
how it is able to reference the location of array elements using *ptr

the output of the program is 2 5
can you please explain how 5 is the output

Comment: Nowhere do you have a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: As for why `&a` *doesn't* return a pointer to a pointer, see e.g [this old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c).

Answer (score 2):

Since `a` is an array of 5 ints, `&a` is a *pointer to an array of 5 ints*. Because pointer arithmetic operates on multiples of the size of the pointed type, `&a+1` is a pointer to a fictional array of 5 ints right after the ints stored in `a`. When you cast that to pointer to int and store in `ptr` you get a pointer to the first int in that array.

In other words,

```
int *ptr = (int*)(&a+1);
```

is equivalent to

```
int *ptr = (a + 5);
```

and this makes `*(ptr-1)` the same as `*(a+4)`, which is the same as `a[4]`, the last element of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the array is the address. So `&a` and `a` have same value. `&a` evaluates to the same address and it creates a pointer of the type `int(*)[size]` which is a pointer to an array, not to a single element. If you increment this pointer, it'll add the size of the entire array, not the size of a single element.

Answer (score -1):

int * ptr = &a[0];    ptr now points the first element of the array (1)   ptr + 1 points to the 2, etc.

Comment: there is difference between (&a+1) and &a[1];

Comment: -1, missing the point. `ptr+1` points to one after `ptr`, but that's one element. And the element here is `int[5]`.

Comment: You are correct.   The real point of my answer should be "Don't do that." and I was trying to show a better way to attach a pointer to an array.   Actually int * ptr = a; and int * ptr=&a[0]; produce identical results, but I have seen a lot of developers confused by the first one (including the poster of this question.)

Comment: The cast in the OP's code is incorrect.  He is changing the type of the pointed-to object from int[5] to int.   Adding 1 to int[5]* points to an address beyond the array.  Adding one to int * points to the next element of the array.