# How to use lfind

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I use `lfind` with this code:

```
int StringPtrCompare(const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2)
{
   return strcmp(*(char(*)[])ptr1, *(char**)ptr2);
}

void Unique()
{
    char*  array[1000] = {0};
    char   buffer[200] = {0};
    size_t count       = 0;
    FILE*  fp          = fopen("text", "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    { 
        error(1, 0, "Couldn't open text for reading");
    }

    while (count < 1000 && fscanf(fp, "%199s", buffer) == 1)
    {
        if (!lfind(buffer, array, &count, sizeof(char*), StringPtrCompare))
        {
            array[count++] = strdup(buffer);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);
        free(array[i]);
    }
}
```

This works, but initially, I was getting segmentation faults if instead, in `StrPtrCompare`, I replaced the cast of the first parameter in `strcmp` with

```
*(char**)ptr1
```

I don't understand, conceptually, why this was the case. 
Isn't

```
(char(*)[]) equivalent to (char**)?
```

Also, I find that if I replace `buffer` with `&buffer` in the while loop statement, the function still works.

Can anyone please explain these two oddities to me?

Comment: I see no function pointers here.

Comment: Also, here's the answer to your last question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c)

Comment: "Function pointers -- `char(*)[]` vs `char**`" - neither of the enumerated pointer types is a pointer-to-function type. Your question has nothing to do with function pointers.

Comment: Okay I edited it. Thanks! Any ideas for the first part?

Comment: Read the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/questions.html), it really helps understand stuff, even up to small details.  Not a big time investment.

Comment: @pyrrhic I'm **trying** very hard to understand your code. It's quite messy, TBH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&buffer` and `buffer` will have same value.Name of an array acts as pointer to its first element that is why you are getting both as same.

Now if we talk about your second problem `(char(*)[]) equivalent to (char**)?`

`(char(*)[])` is not a function pointer.It is pointer to an array of characters.
Array and pointers are not same.Array may decay as pointer.

Please have a look [here](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html)

Comment: I find it weird to see no space between sentences.

Answer (score 1):

`char(*)[]` is a pointer to an array whereas `char**` is a pointer to pointer.

And no, these are not equivalent, for example if you have `char (*arr)[10]`, here `arr` can only be assigned to array of the same size and type. Furthermore you have to pass the address of the array which you do not need to do if you want a pointer to point to an array.

Consider the following usage:

```
char arr[10];

char brr[10];

char (*crr)[10] = &arr; /* note the address-of operator, just passing 'arr' will incense the compiler */

crr = &brr; /* again reassigning but to an array of valid type */
```

Contrast this with `char**`:

```
char *twod_arr[5];

char *twod_brr[4];

char** drr = twod_arr; /* legal, doesn't care about size of array */

drr = twod_brr; /* different array size, still doesn't matter */
```

Comment: Isn't arrin char(*arr)[10] a pointer, though? I thought only arrays couldn't be incremented/decremented?

Comment: @pyrrhic Sorry, misread question, I've updated my answer. Yes, you cannot increment arrays as in `int arr[10]; arr++;` they are called `non-modifiable lvalue` which in effect means that you can get its address but not update its value. Pointers are fine.

Answer (score 1):

What `ptr1` actually represents is the value supplied to `lfind()`, which is the decayed pointer value of the array `buffer`.

What you have cast `ptr1` to is a pointer to an array of `char`. Dereferenced, that expression yields an array of `char`. An array in an expression decays to a value equal to the address of its first element. This works out for you because it so happens that `&buffer` and `buffer` have the same pointer value (although they have different types). In the end, the result of the first argument to `strcmp()` is the same as what was passed to `lfind()`, the decayed pointer value of `buffer`.

When you cast `ptr1` as `(char **)` instead, this is a pointer to a pointer to `char`. Deferencing that yields a pointer to `char`. However, since `ptr1()` actually has the decayed pointer value of the array `buffer`, the result of this dereference causes `strcmp()` to get `sizeof(char *)` bytes of `buffer` treated as a pointer to `char`.

In either case, you have dereferenced a pointer with a type that is incompatible with the object that is actually located at that address, which causes undefined behavior. In one case, it happened to work out, in the other case, it crashed.

You can instead treat `ptr1` as the type that it actually is, a pointer to `char`:

```
int StringPtrCompare(const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2) {
   return strcmp((const char *)ptr1, *(char**)ptr2);
}
```

Comment: Why does ptr1 represent the decayed pointer value of buffer? Doesn't the manual say that it's a "pointer to the key object"? Isn't the key here the buffer array? So shouldn't it be a pointer to the array, buffer?

Comment: @pyrrhic: You have already provided the pointer to the key object when you passed it into the `lfind()` call. `lfind()` is just returning it back in the call to the comparison function.

Comment: So the entire "pointer to the key object" is the buffer array itself? But shouldn't the entire key object be the buffer array itself? So shouldn't a pointer to the keyobject, that is, a pointer to the array, be passed to the comparison function? Sorry if I'm being stupid, I don't know if I'm reading the manual (on Linux) correctly.

Comment: @pyrrhic: I think you are overthinking this. Consider if you were searching over an array of `int` with `lfind()`. You would create an `int` variable, give it the number you wanted to search for, and pass in the address of that variable. In your compare function, you would just get back the pointer you passed in, not a pointer to the pointer you passed in. The point is, `lfind()` passes to the comparison function what was passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

#### Fixing the code

Your code passes things of the wrong type to `lfind`. If the `key` argument is a pointer to some type T, then the `base` argument must be a pointer to an array of T. When you pass `buffer` as `key`, then `buffer`, which is an array of `char`, is automatically converted to a pointer to `char`. Thus, `T` is `char`. So `base` is required to be an array of `char`. However, your `base` is an array of pointers to `char`, so it is the wrong type.

To fix this, add this code in `Unique`, after `buffer` is defined:

```
char *BufferPointer = buffer;
```

Then, to call `lfind`, use:

```
if (!lfind(&BufferPointer, &array, &count, sizeof(char*), StringPtrCompare))
```

With this call, the first parameter is a pointer to a pointer to `char`. Thus, the type T is pointer to `char`. This matches `&array`, which is a pointer to an array of pointer to `char`.

Then, in `StringPtrCompare`, the parameters `ptr1` and `ptr2` will each have type pointer to T. Since T is pointer to `char`, the type of `ptr1` and `ptr2` is pointer to pointer to `char`. (I am ignoring the `const` qualifier for now.) Then you can call `strcmp` this way:

```
int StringPtrCompare(const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2)
{
   return strcmp(* (char **) ptr1, * (char **) ptr2);
}
```

#### Pointers to arrays versus pointers to pointers

A pointer to an array, such as `char (*)[]`, is not the same things as a pointer to a pointer, such as `char **`. If `p` is a pointer to an array, then, at the place where `p` points, there must be an array of elements: The data of the elements must be at that location.

In contrast, if `p` is a pointer to a pointer, then, at the place where `p` points, there must be a pointer: The bytes at that location must contain the value of a pointer.

#### An array versus the address of an array

When `buffer` has type `char [200]`, it is an array of `char`. When you use an array in an expression, it is converted to a pointer to its first element, unless it is the operand of `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or `&` or is a string literal used to initialize an array. When you pass `buffer` to `lfind`, none of those exceptions applies, so `buffer` is converted to the address of its first `char`.

When you pass `&buffer`, this expression is the address of the array. The address of the array has the same value as the address of its first element, but has a different type. However, when you pass either `buffer` or `&buffer` to `lfind`, it is converted to `void *`, because `lfind` is declared to take an argument of that type. Thus, the difference between the types of `buffer` and `&buffer` is lost, and only the value is passed. Since they have the same value, there is no difference.