# how to understand that dereference a pointer to array get a pointer to element?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I used to feel confused about these code

```
int a[3] = {1,2,3};
int b[2][3] = {...};
int (*p1)[3] = &a;  //pointer to array[3]
int (*p2)[3] = b; //same as above
int (*p3)[2][3] = &b; // pointer to array[2][3]
```

then I read some posts<sup>1</sup> and understand the 'mystery' of array name including some explicit and implicit conversion.

So now I know p1 is **a pointer to an array** of 3 element with type int.

But how to understand that `*(int (*)[3])` gets type `int *` or

`*(int (*)[2][3]` gets type `int (*)[3]` ?

Is it something that I should learn by rote?

---

<sup>posts I've read:</sup>

[Is an array name a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer)

[Difference between `a` and `&a` in C++ where `a` is an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20912353/difference-between-a-and-a-in-c-where-a-is-an-array)

[Array to pointer decay and passing multidimensional arrays to functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674094/array-to-pointer-decay-and-passing-multidimensional-arrays-to-functions/12674708#12674708)

---

PS: I don't know if it's a stupid question. But after reading the posts I mentioned above. I still feel kinda weird about that dereference operation stuff. Maybe it's just how the languge syntax work which I should simply bear in mind and stop digging. :D

Comment: In C++, it's best to avoid pointers and arrays as much as possible, but use containers and iterators.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you should understand [array-to-pointer decay](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Array-to-pointer_decay),

> There is an implicit conversion from lvalues and rvalues of array type to rvalues of pointer type: it constructs a pointer to the first element of an array. This conversion is used whenever arrays appear in context where arrays are not expected, but pointers are

For example, `a` (`int [3]`) could decay to `int *`, `b` (`int [2][3]`) could decay to `int (*)[3]`.

Then

> how to understand that `*(int (*)[3])` gets type `int *` or `*(int (*)[2][3]` gets type `int (*)[3]` ?

It depends on the context; more precisely, given `p` with type `int (*)[3]` (i.e. pointer to array), `*p` will get the array (`int [3]`), which could decay to `int *`.

Similarly, given `p` with type `int (*)[2][3]`, `*p` will get the array `int [2][3]`, which could decay to `int (*)[3]`.