# Passing pointer arguments in C functions

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

// this works
void print_stuff (void* buf) {
    printf ("passed arg as buf*: %s\n", buf);
}

/* This works */
void print_stuff_3 (char* buf) {
    printf ("passed arg as char*: %s\n", buf);
}

// this does not work
void print_stuff_2 (char** buf) {
    printf ("%s\n", *buf);
}

int main () {
    char s [] = "hi";

    printf ("s = %s\n", s); 

    // these work
    print_stuff (&s);
    print_stuff_3 (&s);

    // this results in a Segfault
    print_stuff_2(&s);
    return 0;
}
```

I am a bit confused about the way things are passed around in C. I feel like `&s` should be of type `char**`, but it behaves as if it is of type `char*` when passed to a function. Why does this behaviour happen?

In particular, `print_stuff_2` segfaults, whereas I thought that `print_stuff_3` would give an error.

EDIT: To clarify, I expected `print_stuff(&s)` and `print_stuff_3(&s)` to fail (while they succeed), while `print_stuff_2(&s)` fails, whereas I feel it should succeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remember that strings are not fundamental types in C. They are arrays of characters. Therefore

```
char s [] = "hi";
```

makes `s` a `char *` (in terms of variable type), i.e. a pointer to the first character of a 3 character array (`h`, `i` and `NUL`).

So in order to pass a pointer to the string, you what to use your `print_stuff_3`, as `printf()`'s `%s` argument takes exactly that (a pointer to the string, i.e. a pointer to the first character). Call this with `print_stuff_3(s)`.

`print_stuff` works because a pointer is a pointer. It will be translated to a `void *` pointer on calling `print_stuff`, then `printf()`'s `%s` will convert it back to a `char *`. Call this with `print_stuff(s)`.

`print_stuff_2` doesn't work because you are taking the address of where `s` is stored. Had you written `char *s = "hi";` that would work if you used `print_stuff_2(&s)`. You'd pass the address of the pointer, then dereference that (to get the value of the pointer, i.e. the pointer to the first character) in by using `*buf`. Except `buf` then would be a poor choice of name, as you would be passing a pointer to a pointer to characters.

The complication is as follows. As it is, you are doing `&s` which just returns `s` when you have

```
char s [] = "hi";
```

(see [How come an array's address is equal to its value in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c) ), but returns the address at which the pointer variable `s` is stored on the stack if you have:

```
char *s = "hi";
```

Taking the address of an array doesn't really make sense (so evaluates to the address of the first element). You need to use `char *s = "hi";` if you want to take the address of the pointer.

Comment: But I thought (as you actually said) that `char []` is the same as `char*`. And `&(char *)` is `(char**)`. So why isn't `&(char[])` the same as `&(char *)`?

Comment: `char s[] = "hi";` does make `s` (the variable) a `char *` (i.e. a pointer to the first character) but that does not mean it is the same as `char * s = "hi"`. Consider for instance `sizeof s`. The first will return 3, the second the size of a `char *` pointer. Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c - I've clarified the answer a little.

Answer (score 0):

In C, array names are decays to pointer to its first element when passed to a function in most cases. When passing `s` to the function `print_stuff`, `s` decays to pointer to `h`. No need to pass it with `&`. `&s` is of pointer to array (`char (*)[3]`) type, i.e, it is giving the address of the entire array `s`.

In function call

```
print_stuff_3 (&s);
```

your compiler should warn you

```
[Warning] passing argument 1 of 'print_stuff_3' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

> I feel like `&s` should be of type `char*`*, but it behaves as if it is of type `char*` when passed to a function. Why does this behavior happen?

No. You thought wrong. &s is of type `char (*)[3]`.

Comment: You should try running it. Both work. That's why I'm confused.

Comment: It will run but your compiler should through a warning I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: If you call `print_stuff_2` with `&s`, do you think it should run? If yes, try it. It does not. That was my feeling as well.

Comment: No. It should not. `&s` is of type `char (*)[3]`. `print_stuff_2` expects argument of type `char **`. You are passing wrong argument.

Comment: It was my understanding that arrays in C are pointers to the first element, and in particular that `char*` and `char[]` were identical.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. `char *` and `char[]` are not identical except when they are parameter of a function.

Comment: @BlackSheep There is often some confusion about this, it's called "array pointer equivalence", and it rests very much on the nuance that "equivalent" does not mean "equal". http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html but in a nutshell: An array variable, `char a[]` can *decay* to a pointer in normal usage, and does so when given as a function parameter, `void f(char a[])` to prevent arrays passing by value (how much space on the stack would `char a[]` require?).

Answer (score 0):

`void print_stuff (void* buf)` & `void print_stuff_3 (char* buf)` In both functions, `buf` is of `char *` taking address as argument. Which should be `print_stuff (s)` & `print_stuff_3 (s)` respectively as `s` is the base address of char array `s`. So you shouldn't pass `&s` which is address of `s`.

As the below function `buf` is of type `char **`, it will expect address of address like `print_stuff_2(&s)` provided your declaration is `char *s = "hi"`,

```
void print_stuff_2 (char** buf) {
    printf ("%s\n", *buf);
}
```

Comment: What you are saying is that the first two functions should fail but the third one should work (i.e. `print_stuff_2` should work). But actually the exact opposite happens.

Comment: *As the below function buf is of type char **, it will expect address of address like*: Yes true, but it is not expecting `&s`, having type of `char (*)[3]`.