# Why "*(&arr+4)" is different then "&arr[4]"?

Tags: c, pointers, reference

```
int arr[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

I am performing address operation tests, to increase my understanding of ref and deref.
Here is a lot of confusion.

I found out that `&*(arr+4)` uses the same address as `&arr[4]`but I never met such assignment as `&*`

Also I figured that `*(&arr+4)` uses the same address as `&arr+4` but it doesn't make any sense to me.

I couldn't find info about that, so I will just ask here, why `*(&arr+4)` uses the same address as `&arr+4` and why `*(&arr+4)` is different then `&arr[4]`?

Comment: By doing so:
`sprintf(text, "%i, %i", *(&arr+4), &arr+4);`
Same adress appear.

Comment: @Edenia: Since that `sprintf` has undefined behaviour, you can't really conclude much from it.

Comment: Even though... what is correct and what is not?

Comment: @Mahonri Moriancumer
Thanks for the edit, i am not a native english speaker, but im doing my best.

Comment: [It seems my comment about the types was incorrect.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2528328/694733)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`arr` is an array:

```
arr: int[6]
[0|1|2|3|4|5]
```

When used in an expression other than `sizeof arr` or `&arr`, an array decays to a pointer to the first element of the array:

```
(arr+0): int *
[*]
 |
 v
[0|1|2|3|4|5]
```

When an integral value is added to a pointer, you get a pointer to the address that is `(sizeof (T)) * n` bytes later in memory (where T is the type pointed to by the pointer, and `n` is the integral value added to the pointer):

```
(arr+4): int *
        [*]
         |
         v
[0|1|2|3|4|5]
```

When a pointer is dereferenced, you get the value that was pointed to:

```
*(arr+4): int
          4 /* specifically, the 4 in the fifth position in `arr` */
[0|1|2|3|[4]|5]
```

When the address is taken of an `int`, you get a pointer that points to that int:

```
&*(arr+4): int *
        [*] /* notice, this is the same as (arr+4) */
         |
         v
[0|1|2|3|4|5]
```

Array indexing is equivalent to pointer-addition followed by dereferencing:

```
arr[4] == *(arr+4) /* see above for definition of *(arr+4) */
```

So yes... `&*(arr+4)` and `&arr[4]` are equivalent.

When the address of an array is taken, you get a pointer to an array:

```
&arr: int (*)[6]
[*] /* points to the array as a whole, not the first element of the array */
 |
 v
 [0|1|2|3|4|5]
```

When you increment that pointer, the same rules apply as above:

```
                                    &arr + 4: int(*)[6]
               /*points into some memory that*/    [*]
               /* isn't part of the array... */     |
               /*  undefined behaviour       */     v
[0|1|2|3|4|5][x|x|x|x|x|x][x|x|x|x|x|x][x|x|x|x|x|x][x|x|x|x|x|x]
```

Since this has undefined behaviour, you can't reason about it without reference to the underlying machine architecture and compiler implementation.

If we imagine that it were well defined (as would be the case if `arr` were part of a larger array)... we can continue. Dereferencing a pointer to an array gives the array again:

```
             /*the 5th array in this array of arrays*/ *(&arr+4): int[6]
   [0|1|2|3|4|5][x|x|x|x|x|x][x|x|x|x|x|x][x|x|x|x|x|x][[x|x|x|x|x|x]]
```

You would find that `*(&arr+4)` and `(&arr+4)` have the same address, since `*(&arr+4)` decays into a pointer to the first element of `*(&arr+4)`, and an array starts at its first element, so a pointer to the start of an array and a pointer to the first element of an array would be identical.

`*(&arr+4)` is different from `&arr[4]` since it refers to a completely different thing (see above).

Comment: Wow, thanks for the deep explanation.
I think your explanation has nothing to do with the one here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c
Which didn't help as yours did. :)