# Using addressof with memcpy of 2 arrays

Tags: c, arrays

Why is it that both the `memcpy` below produces the same result:

```
int arr1[5] = {some_data1};
int arr2[5] = {some_data2};

memcpy(&arr1, &arr2, (5 * sizeof(int)));
memcpy(arr1, arr2, (5 * sizeof(int)));
```

Why doesn't the first memcpy see a double pointer for arr1 and arr2? Is it because the array name is not truly a pointer but rather an identifier for a variable of the "array" type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How come an array's address is equal to its value in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c)

Comment: (offtopic: passing `5` as size in memcpy is wrong)

Answer (score 3):

> Why doesn't the first memcpy see a double pointer for `arr1` and `arr2`?

Bluntly speaking, because it is not a double pointer.

> Is it because the array name is not truly a pointer but rather an identifier for a variable of the "array" type?

Absolutely! This happens precisely because arrays are *not* pointers, despite many misleading similarities shared by the two kinds of C objects.

The behavior is the same because both expressions produce numerically identical `void*` pointers when passed to `memcpy`.

Comment: Thank you. Updated my question. Hasty pseudo code, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

Because in C, when `a` is an array we have this:

```
 (void *) a == (void *) &a
```

the address of `&a` (pointer to the array) and of `&a[0]` (pointer to the first element of the array) is the same, only the type is different.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c) - "The name of an array usually evaluates to the address of the first element of the array, so array and &array have the same value."

Comment: If it's a duplicate, use the _flag_ button, don't post an answer that just points to the other question.

Comment: @jarmod Thank you, I didn't find that question prior to posting. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

In some contexts, when you use an array name it is converted to the address of the array. Passing an array as a function argument is one of those contexts. But using the array with the `&` operator is not -- it returns the address of the array.

Answer (score 0):

in array, your array variable(arr1 amd arr2) naturally represent base address of the array, you do not need to give &(address of operator).
arr1==&arr1