# Pointer of pointer: &foo == foo?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

```
#include <cstdio>

typedef struct {
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
} Foo;

int main() {
  Foo foo[42];
  printf("foo = %p\n", foo);
  printf("&foo = %p\n", &foo);
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile this program with `g++` and run it, it produces the following output.

```
foo = 0xbf8caea8
&foo = 0xbf8caea8
```

This is not what I expected. When I derefence `foo`, I would expect to get the **value of** `foo[0].a` and when I dereference `&foo`, I would expect to get a **pointer on** `foo[0].a`.

How can these two pointers be equal?

Comment: Why would you expect that?

Comment: Google for *arrays versus pointers in C++*. An array *decays* to a pointer.

Comment: `foo` and `&foo` aren't similar?

Comment: *What* dereference? To dereference a pointer you would use the dereference operator `*`.

Comment: `foo`, `foo[0]` and `foo[0].a` shares the same address.

Comment: I know that arrays are stored as pointers, so `foo` is basically of type `Foo*`. In my understanding, `&foo` should be of type `Foo**` and therefore foo != &foo.

Comment: @MBober Arrays are *most definitely **not*** stored as pointers. A pointer is an address (typically 4 or 8 bytes). An array is a sequence of objects. In C and C++, arrays *decay* to pointers - an array can be implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: Thanks everyone. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2528999/990968 answered my question. I just wasn't able to find it using the SO search. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of them as addresses rather than pointers, because `&foo` there for example is not a pointer, rather just the address of the `foo` variable.

What does the `foo` variable stand for?

It stands for the array of `Foo`s you've declared. This array starts from a point in memory, exactly where the first element of the array starts, logically.

Think of a chain in real life. The whole chain starts from the exact same location as the flrst bit of chain starts. Their sizes are different, but both originate from the same location in space.

The case is just like that for arrays. `&foo` is where the whole chain starts, `&foo[0]` - which is what `foo` is - starts from that same location.

Comment: My problem was that I thought that `foo` always decays to a pointer to `foo[0]`. I wasn't aware of the fact that this is true **unless `foo` is an operand of unary operator `&`** (or `sizeof`).