# why do both methods of inputting string work?

Tags: c++, string, arrays

suppose i have the code:

1a.

```
char str1[50];
scanf("%s",&str1);
```

this works fine.

1b.

```
char str1[50];
scanf("%s",str1);
```

this also works fine.

however, the following code cant take input from user.

1c.

```
char str1[50];
scanf("%c",str1[0]);
```

I know that & is required to take input from user and store it in an address, but what is happening in first case ?

Comment: It's not about addresses as much as it's about types. `str1` is basically a pointer. `str1[0]`, however, is a `char`.

Comment: The array is decaying to a pointer (in 1b). Those are some keywords that should help you in googling this phenomenon.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How come an array's address is equal to its value in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c)

Comment: str1[0] also points to base address, right?it points to first character of string. correct me if i'm wrong. @raina77ow

Comment: @guitar_geek No, it _is_ the first character. &str1[0], however, points right there - and it's actually the same as `str1` (apart from type).

Comment: The first example is strictly speaking UB, and all are different.

Comment: my bad. @raina77ow ,yea so str1 is same as &str1[0] . so in 1a. &str must be same as &&str1[0] , which cant be right,right ?

Comment: No, it's not. Guys, do you ever follow the links in the comments?

Comment: @pm100: `str1` is no pointer...

Comment: @raina77ow: That's not a duplicate because it only explains part of the question why example 1 seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to read in a string is either of these:

```
scanf("%s", &str1[0]);    // Correct
scanf("%s", str1);        // Also correct
```

The first one is explicitly correct--you want to pass the address of the first `char`. The second, it turns out, is equivalent. When you pass an array to a function, it silently "decays" to a pointer. The compiler converts arguments like `array` into `&array[0]`.

```
scanf("%c",str1[0]);      // Incorrect
```

Passing the first character instead of the *address* of the first character is flat out wrong. This will either fail to compile, or will very likely crash when you run the program. A character is very different from an address.

```
scanf("%s", &str1);       // Undefined behavior
```

This is wrong, but not "flat out" wrong, if I may be allowed to make such a distinction.

Passing `&str1` is a common error. The reason is subtle indeed. `&str[0]` is the address of the first character of the string. `&str` is the address of the entire 50-character array. The subtlety here is that these will in fact be the same address in memory--an array starts at its first character.

So why is this wrong?

The answer is in typing.

- The type of `&str[0]` is `char *` -- pointer to character. That's the expected type when you use `%s`.
- The type of `&str` is `char (*)[50]` -- pointer to a 50-character array. This is *not* the same thing as `char *`. For further explanation, see: [How come an array's address is equal to its value in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c).

The *values* of `&str` and `&str[0]` are equal, but the *types* are different. This type mismatch is, pedantically speaking, an error. It causes undefined behavior.

I know what you're thinking. "Okay, smart guy--if this is an error, then why does it work, huh?" Well, C is a funny language. It's really trusting. Overly trusting, really. If you tell it to jump off a cliff, it'll jump off that cliff. It doesn't go out of its way to verify that you're doing absolutely correct and sensible things.

There are lots of times when you can ask it to do something that's technically invalid. Compilers aren't required to diagnose and prevent undefined behavior. In the name of efficiency, it's permissible for them to do anything they want: crash, or print an error message... or, commonly, appear to actually work. This is one of those cases. The values of `&str` and `&str[0]` are the same, and because `scanf()` is a varargs function, not all compilers will catch the type mismatch.

The morale is: don't rely on the compiler to tell you every time you make a mistake. If you mess up and invoke undefined behavior, you may get away with it for a while. Your code may appear to work. But you're sitting on a ticking time bomb. One day it will blow up in your face.

Comment: isnt &str is the address of the variable that stores the address of the 50-char array?

Comment: `str1` is that very array. It doesn't hold the array's address, it **is** the array. `str1` is the array and `&str` is the address of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take it all one-by-one:

> I know that & is required to take input from user and store it in an address, but what is happening in first case ?

Actually, that's wrong. You cannot store things in an address, as addresses are not modifiable.
What you probably wanted to say is, that you know C is strictly pass-by-value, and thus to let a function modify an object you need to pass a pointer to it (which neccessitates using `&`).

Now, let's look at your code:

```
char str1[50];
scanf("%s",&str1);
```

This is [**Undefined Behavior**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984), because `scanf` expects a pointer to character-type (`char*` `unsigned char*` `signed char*` and `const`-qualified versions).
Passing a value of type `char(*)[50]` is not ok. Why does it still *work*?
Because [the address of an array and its first element are guaranteed to be identical](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2528318), your implementation has only one data-pointer-type, and you had the luck (which will bite you later).

This one is ok, if one disregards the buffer-overflow waiting to happen. Always pass a proper limit:

```
char str1[50];
scanf("%s",str1);
```

Should be:

```
char str1[50];
scanf("%49s",str1);
```

Your next example does something completely different, reading the single next `char` from the input-stream into `*str1`:

```
char str1[50];
scanf("%c",str1[0]);
```

That's probably not what you wanted.

Additional note: Always check how many fields where assigned, that's the return-value of `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare an array such as `char str1[50]`, memory for the array is allocated on the stack and looks like:

```
str1
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 0  | 1  |   ........   | 48 | 49 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Now, if you take the elements of the array, they are:

```
str1[0]
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 0  | 1  |   ........   | 48 | 49 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+

     str1[1]
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 0  | 1  |   ........   | 48 | 49 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

etc.

For arrays like that, it so happens that the address of `str1` is the same
as the address of `str1[0]`.

Synantically, the correct way of using using `scanf` is:

```
scanf("%s", str1);
```

or

```
scanf("%s", &str1[0]);
```

It works with

```
scanf("%s", &str1);
```

since `&str1` and `&str1[0]` are the same.

They won't work if you use a dynamically allocated array.

```
char* str2 = malloc(50);
```

Let's say the value returned by `malloc` is `AAA`

The memory layout for `str2` looks like:

```
str2
+-----+
| AAA |
+-----+
```

The memory at address AAA looks like:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 0  | 1  |   ........   | 48 | 49 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

The elements of the array are located starting at `AAA`.

```
str2[0]
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 0  | 1  |   ........   | 48 | 49 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+

     str2[1]
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 0  | 1  |   ........   | 48 | 49 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

For this case, `&str2` is not the same as `&str2[0]`. If you use:

```
scanf("%s", &str2);
```

you will experience undefined behavior.

Comment: Your first graph looks to my eyes like you're suggesting that `str1` **is** a pointer.  It's not.

Comment: @JohnDibling, I don't know how else to draw the diagram.

Comment: leave out the pointer from the objects name to its representation?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the real issue here is that C / C++ treats array names as references rather than values, combined with the fact that some C / C++ compilers will treat an explicit reference to an array name, such as &str, the same as str. For example with the following code, some 32 bit compilers (Visual C/C++ 4.0) will output 32 for sizeof str1 and 32 for size of &str1, while others (Visual Studio 2005 or later) will output 32 for sizeof str1 and 4 for sizeof &str1

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
char str1[32];
    printf("%d %d\n", sizeof(str1), sizeof(&str1));
    return (0);
}
```