# Alias address of struct array as int

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, strict-aliasing

```
struct test
{
    char member1;
    char member2;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct test structure[] = {'h', 'i'};
    static void* p = &structure;

    printf("%i", *((int*)p));

    return 0;
}
```

We all know that `structure` should point to the address of the first element in the struct. Why by dereferencing it like that, it returns the address itself instead?

Comment: An `int` is not a `char`. Pointers to those are not interchangeable.

Comment: What are you using to compile this? clang and gcc should both fail by default on this code, even with the missing `;` fixed.

Comment: I think this is just a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c

Comment: @BillLynch I agree that he is misunderstanding that `(int *)structure == (int *)&structure` here although there is a bot more going on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code exhibits an undefined behaviour.

You are casting a `structure *` to type `int *` and dereferencing. When (mostly) the size of `int` is more, you are accessing offbound memory. (This is one reason, there are a few more)

```
+---+---+---+---+
| h | i | ? | ? |
+---+---+---+---+
Print as int: ? ? i h if machine is little endian

In ascii coding
+---+---+---+---+
| 68| 69| ? | ? |
+---+---+---+---+
Print as int: ?? ?? 69 68
```

[Live code here](http://ideone.com/qe2GnK)

Correct usage of structures is:

```
struct test s1   = {'h', 'i'};
struct test s2[] = { {'t', 'o'}, {'d', 'o'} };

printf("s1   : %c, %c\n", s1.member1, s1.member2);
printf("s2[0]: %c, %c\n", s2[0].member1, s2[0].member2);
printf("s2[1]: %c, %c\n", s2[1].member1, s2[1].member2);
```

Comment: Even if i change it to `char*` it still won't return value but address. / variadic random characters in this case /

Comment: Yes so how to obtain the `'h'` ?

Comment: @BillLynch If declaration is struct test structure[] = { {'h'}, {'i'}};, then it would be h0i0. (0 is not character). [Otherwise as stated](http://ideone.com/yl94br)

Comment: Thank you elza. It works if i don't use the ampersand though.

Answer (score 1):

This causes undefined behaviour due to violation of the *strict aliasing rule*.

When reading via the expression `*(int *)some_pointer` , it is only valid in the following cases:

- `some_pointer` points to an object declared with type `int` or `unsigned int` (optionally with `const` or `volatile` qualifiers).
- `some_pointer` points into dynamically-allocated storage that has previously had an `int` or `unsigned int` written to exactly that location.

Some compilers may optimize according to this rule. For more information about the benefits of this, [see here](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html)

Even if your char array had at least `sizeof(int)` bytes in it, the compiler might still ignore (or worse!) your attempt to alias those as an `int`.  Despite this fact it's not uncommon in "real" code for people to try this, which is why a lot of existing code has to be compiled with `-fno-strict-aliasing`.

NB. There may also be undefined behaviour if `structure` is not correctly aligned for `int`.

Comment: I am trying to reinvent `fread` and make it to do the same thing but from another instance instead of file stream.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an array called structure. Its name gives the address. So you don't need to have & operator before it.

You can have either p = &structure[0];  or p = structure;