# Why doesn't my string store anything?

Tags: c, string, char, store, scanf

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
char string1[20], append_string[40];
char *string2 = "APPENDED"; /* string to be appended */

/* prompt for string 1 */
printf("Enter string1: ");
scanf_s("%s", &string1);
while (!strcmp(string1, "done") == 0)
{
    printf("Before append. \nString1: %s \nString2: %s\n\n", string1, string2);
    mystrappend(string1, string2, append_string);
    printf("After append. \nString1: %s \nString2: %s \nAppended string: %s\n\n", string1,            string2, append_string);

    // prompt for string 1 
    printf("Enter string1: ");
    scanf_s("%s", &string1);
   }

 return 0;
 }
```

Why doesn't `String1` store anything after input?
I have the header files of `stdio.h`, `conio.h`, `string.h` and `stdafx.h` included.

Comment: And how is `mystrappend` implemented?

Comment: Atm, i'm still working on it, but even if its empty shouldnt String1 have something inside of it when I input something?

Comment: I see. I think your `scanf_s` call shouldn't take the address of the array, just `scanf_s("%s", string1)`.

Comment: Still prints out nothing for String1..?

Comment: I've checked on the [`scanf_s` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/w40768et.aspx). It requires a buffer size after string arguments, so it should probably be `scanf_s("%s", string1, sizeof(string1));`. Or use plain old `scanf`. These functions return a value, which you should check.

Comment: Ive had to change some properties inside Microsoft Visio, thanks for your information, got it working

Comment: @MOehm but isnt `&OfArray  == OfArray` for array decay?

Comment: @Zaibis: Their "raw" values are the same, but they have different types: [See here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c) or in Cool Guy's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [the documentation of `scanf_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx),

> **Remarks:**
>
> [...]
>
> Unlike `scanf` and `wscanf`, `scanf_s` and `wscanf_s` require the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type `c`, `C`, `s`, `S`, or string control sets that are enclosed in `[]`. The buffer size in characters is passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable.

So, the `scanf_s`

```
scanf_s("%s", &string1);
```

is wrong because of two reasons:

1. `%s` expects a `char*`, but you give the argument `&string1` which is of type `char(*)[20]`. This leads to Undefined Behavior.
2. As seen in the quote above, you need to pass a third argument denoting the size of the buffer.

Fix problem #1 by using `string1` instead of `&string1`. `string1` will "decay" into a pointer to its first element(`char*`).

Fix problem #2 by using a third argument denoting the size of the buffer using `sizeof` or `_countof`.

After fixing these problems, your `scanf_s` should look like

```
scanf_s("%s", string1, sizeof(string1));
```

or

```
scanf_s("%s", string1, _countof(string1));
```