# Pointer and array 'a' and '&a' giving same output?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Why do both of them print the same address? As per my understanding, 'a' is a pointer to the first location of the array i.e value of 'a' is the address of first location of array.

With j=a, we are copying the value of first location of array to j. But &a refers to the address of 'a' which should be distinct from the value in 'a'.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int a[2]={1,2}, *j;
j = a;
printf("%u\n", j);
printf("%u\n", &a);
}

/*OUTPUT:

1356487632
1356487632

*/
```

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24468853/2455888) is the answer.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c?lq=1

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/27617195/1382251.