# Why the name of the array, the address of the array and the value of the array are all the same?

Tags: c, arrays, memory-address

This is a bidimensional array. I understand that the name of the array points to the first element in the array, that is &array[0][0]. But when I try to print, the name of the array, the address of the array and the value of the array are all the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int array[4][2]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    printf("%d    %d\n",
           &array[0][0], array[0][0]);
    printf("%d    %d    %d    %d\n",
           array, &array, *array, **array);
}
```

OUTPUT

```
2686704    1
2686704    2686704    2686704    1
```

Comment: You should add a language tag.

Comment: Can u share the output. Use gdb for debugging. It is very useful

Comment: I have sample output in my answer. (And I know using %u for pointers is a nono :)

Comment: Is this just a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have a pointer variable. It is an array (expression), which is internally converted into the address of the first element in most contexts.

A pointer would be `int (*arrptr)[4][2] = &array;`. The difference is rather good explained in the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=aryptr)

```
int array[4][2]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
int (*ptr1)[4][2]=&array;
static int (*ptr2)[4][2];
ptr2=&array;
printf("%p                   %d\n",
        &array[0][0], array[0][0]);
printf("%p    %p      %p     %d\n",
        array,&array, *array,**array);
printf("%p    %p      %p     %d\n",
        ptr1, &ptr1,  *ptr1, ***ptr1);
printf("%p    %p      %p     %d\n",
        ptr2, &ptr2,  *ptr2, ***ptr2);

0xbfbfec24                                1
0xbfbfec24    0xbfbfec24    0xbfbfec24    1
0xbfbfec24    0xbfbfec20    0xbfbfec24    1
0xbfbfec24    0x804970c     0xbfbfec24    1
                      ^^
```

Here you see that the pointer is a different address in the stack and the static pointer an even more different address in the heap.

Comment: using `%u` to print pointers causes undefined behaviour (at least use `%p`, strictly speaking the pointer should also be cast to `void *`).

Comment: @MattMcNabb I know (i wrote this in my comment above), I just did not want to derivate too much from the original example.

Comment: Deviating from the original example in order to correct it is always appropriate. Especially when the original example didn't even use `%u`.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths thanks, I used %p and changed the output - I skip the casts.

Comment: "It is an array, which is internally treated as its actual address." Not exactly. An array expression is, in most contexts, *converted* to the address of its first element.

Answer (score 1):

In your code (corrected):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int array[4][2] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    printf("%p    %d\n",
           (void *) &array[0][0], array[0][0]);
    printf("%p    %p    %p    %d\n",
           (void *) array, (void *) &array, (void *) *array, **array);
}
```

in the last `printf()` call:

- `array` is a two-dimensional array of `int`, but in this context the name of an array decays to a pointer to its first element. Its first element is `array[0]`, not `array[0][0]`, as evidenced by the fact that:

  ```
  int * p = array;
  ```

  should give you a warning, while:

  ```
  int (*p)[2] = array;
  ```

  should not.

  Because of the way arrays are laid out in memory it is, however, also true that the address of `array` is the same as the address of `array[0]` which is the same as the address of `array[0][0]`.
- `&array` is the address of the array, which is the same as the address of its first element...and so on.
- `*array` is equivalent to `array[0]`. The type of `array[0]` is array of `int` of size `2`. Since `array[0]` is itself an array, it also here decays into a pointer to its first element, which as explained is the same address as `&array`, and the same address `array` decays to, here.
- `**array` is equivalent to `array[0][0]` which, finally, is an actual `int`, not an array, and therefore doesn't decay to any kind of address, it's just the value `1`.

That's why the first three expressions all evaluate to the same address.

Note that `%p` is for pointers, and because `printf()` is a variadic function, the compiler cannot implicitly convert your pointers to `void *` like it normally would, because it doesn't know `printf()` is expecting a `void *` for a `%p` specifier, so you should explicitly cast them to `void *`. In reality, you'll probably be looking a long time to find a modern desktop computer where `void *`, `int *`, `int (*)[2]`, and `int (*)[4][2]` don't have the exact same representation, but being correct is better than not being correct.

Answer (score 0):

They aren't the same thing.

An array is an object consisting of a sequence of one or more contiguous elements, all of the same type. A 2-dimensional array is nothing more or less than an array of arrays.

The *name* of an array is an expression. Like any expression of array type, it is, in most but not all contexts, implicitly converted to a pointer to the array's first element. The exceptions are when it's the operand of `sizeof` (`sizeof arr` yields the size of the array object, not the size of a pointer) and when it's the operand of unary `&` (`&arr` yields the address of the entire array).

The *address* of an array is like the address of any object. It refers to a particular memory address, and it has a type: pointer to the array type. For example, given:

```
int arr[10];
```

the expression `arr` (if it's not the operand of `&` or `sizeof`) yields the address of `arr[0]`, and is of type `int*`. The expression `&arr` yields the address of the entire array; it's the same memory location, but it's of type `int (*)[10]`, or "pointer to array of 10 `int`s".

The *value* of an array is generally not something that's you can directly refer to. It consists of the values of the elements of the array.

Now let's look at your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int array[4][2]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
```

This is more clearly written as:

```
    int array[4][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}};
```

```
    printf("%d    %d\n",
           &array[0][0], array[0][0]);
```

`array[0][0]` is an `int` object, so `&array[0][0]` is its address, and is of type `int*`. The correct way to print an address (pointer value) is to use the `%p` format; it expects an argument of type `void*`, so you should convert it.

```
    printf("%p    %d\n", (void*)&array[0][0], array[0][0]);

    printf("%d    %d    %d    %d\n",
           array, &array, *array, **array);
```

`array` is an expression of array type, so it "decays" to a pointer to that array's first element. That element is of type `int[2]`, so the pointer is of type `int(*)[2]`. Again, you should use `%p` and convert to `void*`.

`&array` is the address of the entire array. It's of type `int(*)[4][2]`.

In `*array`, the subexpression `array` decays to a pointer. `*` then dereferences that pointer, which gives us an object of type `int[2]` (the first element of the array). That's an expression of array type, so it decays *again* to a pointer to that array's first element. It's of type `int*`.

In `**array`, `*array` is evaluated as above; it's a pointer to an `int` object. The next `*` dereferences that pointer, yielding an `int` value.

All the pointer values you've printed point to the same memory address, but they're variously of type `int*`, `int(*)[2]`, or `int(*)[2][4]`. Each of these pointers, when converted to `void*`, yields the same value, and all of them

```
}
```

Putting this together, here's a corrected version of your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int array[4][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}};
    printf("%p    %d\n",
           (void*)&array[0][0], array[0][0]);
    printf("%p    %p    %p    %d\n",
           (void*)array, (void*)&array, (void*)*array, **array);
}
```

The output on my (64-bit) system is:

```
0x7fffc5070b30    1
0x7fffc5070b30    0x7fffc5070b30    0x7fffc5070b30    1
```

The relationship between arrays and pointers in C can be confusing. Much of the confusion can be cleared up by reading section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Answer (score -3):

The internal representation of Array is as follows. Arrays are nothing but constant pointers. They are represented as continuous memory locations.

[image: Sample example]

So if we access the array as `A[1]` it is converted into `*(A + 1)` i.e `A` here points to address of first element and 1 represents offset. If the array is of type `int` then 1 represents the `sizeof int` for e.g consider size of `int` as 4B. So 4 bytes is added to `A` which will now make it points to second element in the array `A`. So in 2D array it would be represented as `*(*(A + i) + j)` where `i` is row and `j` is column. So based on it you will get the output as mentioned above

Comment: The `A + i` part of your `*(*(A + i) + j)` arithmetic actually relies on pointers and arrays not being the same. If `i` was measured in terms of `sizeof(int)` or even `sizeof(int *)`, then you'd be lucky to get the element you were after.