# Function is adding to two dimensions of array instead of one C

Tags: c, linux

When I try to save variable to two dimensional array, it saves it in two dimensions [0] [1] instead of one.

For example:

- `dodajDoKolejki(1,1)` // Adding numer 1 to dimension 1
- priting array gives me result shown below, but it shouldn't change kolejka[0]

  ```
  kolejka[0] = 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
  kolejka[1] = 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  ```

---

```
int (*kolejka)[2]; // Global variable
...
int queue[2][ilSamochodow+1]; 
kolejka = &queue;
...

    void dodajDoKolejki(int numerWatku,int miasto)
    //Adding numbers from 1-... to random dimensions (given as miasto)
    {
        //Checking if number already exists( int istnieje ) in array
        int istnieje = 0;
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<ilSamochodow+1;i++)
        {
            if(kolejka[miasto][i] == numerWatku)
                istnieje = 1;
        }

        if(istnieje == 0)
        {
            //Looking for 0 in array, if found we can save on its index( == 0)
            i = 0; // Indeks miejsca, w ktorym zapiszemy numerWatku
            while(kolejka[miasto][i] != 0)
                i++;

            kolejka[miasto][i] = numerWatku;
            printf("\nDodano %d do kolejki miasta %d",numerWatku,miasto);
            wypiszKolejke2(miasto);
        }
        else
            printf("\nBlad. Nie mozna dodac, poniewaz watek jest w kolejce!");
    }
```

Comment: The parenthesis on the first line are confusing and unneccessar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dimensions and assignment of your kolejka variable are incorrect. Should be:

```
int (*kolejka)[ilSamochodow+1]; // Global variable
int queue[2][ilSamochodow+1]; 
kolejka = queue;
```

based on how you are trying to use it. queue is an array of pointers to an array of ilSamochodow+1 ints. So to declare a pointer that is compatible with queue, you need to declare a pointer to an array of 
ilSamochodow+1 ints.

Answer (score 0):

This ...

```
int (*kolejka)[2]; // Global variable
```

... declares a pointer to an array of 2 `int`s.  This ...

```
int queue[2][ilSamochodow+1];
```

... declares an array of 2 arrays of `ilSamochodow+1` `int`s.  Therefore, this ...

```
kolejka = &queue;
```

... assigns a pointer of incompatible type to variable `kolejka`.  (Your compiler ought to be warning you about that.)  Dereferencing the pointer therefore produces undefined behavior.

You would be ok if you instead declared `queue` like this:

```
int queue[ilSamochodow+1][2];
```

or if you declared `kolejka` like this:

```
int (*kolejka)[ilSamochodow+1];
```

Since `kolejka` is a global, the latter supposes that `ilSamochodow` resolves to a compile-time constant, which appears unlikely to be the case for you.

Additionally, although `&queue` and `queue` resolve to the same address in most contexts, they have different type (as discussed [elsewhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c)).  Once the order-of-dimensions issue is cleared up, the type-correct assignment would be:

```
kolejka = queue;
```