# Extract float numbers from integer array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, floating-point

I have an integer array, of which, I know the first 4 bytes are a float the secon 4 bytes are another float and so on; to extract float numbers I use a float pointer like this:

```
uint8_t  l_buffer[17];
float32  num1 = *(float*)&(l_buffer);
float32  num2 = *(float*)&(l_buffer[4]);
```

and all works perfectly, but I don't understand why!!!! In fact I tried to use the pointers without the '*':

```
float32  num1 = (float*)&(l_buffer);
float32  num2 = (float*)&(l_buffer[4]);
```

but it doesn't work. Sorry, but (float*)&(l_buffer) is not a cast to a floating pointer to the first location of l_buffer array ? Why I need to add the '*' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `(float*)(anystuff)`you got a float pointer.

So yes `(float*)&(l_buffer)` is a cast to a **float pointer** to the first location of the array.

But there is no explicit conversion from a float pointer to a float so this will not work:

```
float  num1 = (float*)&(l_buffer);  // error (float*) is not (float)
```

But you can want to read the pointed value like `float f = *(pFloatPointer)` , and that why thus this will work:

```
float  num1 = *(float*)&(l_buffer); // ok *(float*) is a (float)
```

Also cast to a `float*` give you facilities for indexing:

```
float f1 = *(float*)&(l_buffer[4]);    // 4th element of a uint8_t array
float f2 = ((float*)l_buffer)[1];      // 1th element of a float array
                                       // So f1 == f2
```

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard, in this case, because it is cast to a float* it will have no effect, you can see an explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c