# Arrays as scanf's function arguments. Adress operator

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, scanf, variadic-functions

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char s[32];

example_1:
  scanf("%s", s);
  printf("%s\n", s);

example_2:
  scanf("%s", &s[0]);
  printf("%s\n", s);

example_3:
  scanf("%s", &s);
  printf("%s\n", s);
}
```

1. Why does #3 work the same way as other 2?
2. Is #3 valid at all? Why?

Comment: See here: [How come an arrays address is equal to its value in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Variant one depends on [array decay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432), and is thus valid.

   (Arrays decay to pointers to their first element in most contexts, exceptions are: Address-of (`&s`), `sizeof s`, `_Alignas(s)` and `_Alignof(s)`.)
2. Variant two does what array-decay would do manually and more verbose, and is thus worse.
3. Variant three is strictly [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984), though it happens to work on most implementations.
   The sticking point is that `&s` is not of type `char*` after default promotions, though it points to the right address.

Seems to work is the most treacherous subset of UB.

Answer (score 2):

While the types of the three are different :

- `s` is a `char[32]` (an array of 32 `char`s), which transparently decays to a `char*` where needed
- `&s[0]` is a `char*` (a pointer to `char`)
- `&s` is a `char(*)[32]` (a pointer to an array of 32 `char`s)

they all resolve to the same value (the start address of the character array). So, when passing it to `printf`, which expects a `char*`, the result will be the same for all 3 (assuming the object representation of a `char(*)[32]` is the same as that of a `char*`, which is implementation dependent, but commonly the case).

Only the first two are valid though - the third just works by accident.

Comment: Understood. So, just to be precise, is it correct to assume that case #3 is invalid because it violates *printf function format specification from the standard (in terms that if supplied argument doesn't correspond to format type it invokes UB straight away)? Or is here anyting else violated?

Comment: @HighPredator: Yes, that's it.

Comment: @Deduplicator, thanks. I got one more question to follow this topic. Let's say we have the following:
    
 >   char s[32];
 >  char dest[32];
 >   /*  some code here */
 >   memcpy(&dst, &s, sizeof(s));

Is this wrong as well?

P.S. sorry, I'm still struggling with the editor here...

Comment: @HighPredator: As `s` is of the proper size (It's a `char[32]`), that "works". It's unneccessarily error-prone, due to being unrelated though.

Comment: @Deduplicator, could you please clarify the "unrelated" part a bit? Not sure I understand it correctly.

Comment: @HighPredator: In that snippet, there's no obvious reason why they all should be the same size, aside from they just are.

Comment: @Deduplicator, what about the fact that we supply memcpy with arguments of type (char*)[32] instead of char*? Will it always resolve to a correct memory address or it can be classified as a logical error or smth?

Comment: @HighPredator: `memcpy` is not a variadic function. The prototype says the argument is of type `void*`, and thus the compiler silently converts (or complains if that's impossible, because you gave something which isn't a data-pointer, or is cv-qualified).

Comment: @Deduplicator, memcpy, sorry. Made an edit. So just a logical errror, right?

Comment: @HighPredator: It's perfectly valid to take the address of the array to pass it to `memcpy`, it's just very unusual (I personally don't do it, but one could make a point this is more consistent with other `memcpy` calls; what usually does indicate a mistake, though, is passing the size of the source instead of the target). Same for the `printf` call: The value is correct, it's just the type mismatch: `scanf("%31s", (char *)&s);` would be well-defined (but ugly).

Comment: "when passing it to printf, which expects a char*, the result will be the same for all 3"  - true on common hardware but not guaranteed . Arguments don't get converted to match the format specifier; they have to match it already. The argument of the wrong type may be using a different value representation even though the value is the same.

Comment: @MattMcNabb : while that's theoretically possible, I haven't seen a platform that uses a different object representation for the address of an array, and the address of the first item of that array. But I'll add a caveat.