# DevC++ array issue

Tags: c, arrays, dev-c++

Why right value and left value in array are the same?

Refer to the code: why `&a` and `a` have the same value?

CODE:

```
int main()
{
    int a[4];
    *a = 3;
    printf("&array: %p    array: %p   array[0]: %d", &a, a, *a);
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

> &array: 000000000023FE50    array: 000000000023FE50   array[0]: 3

Answer (score 1):

Here, `&a` and `a` gives the same output because, in `C`, array name *behaves* (or better, gets evaluated to) as the address of the first element of the array.

Comment: thank's for the link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c)