# Why we don't require to dereference the pointer to a string while passing to printf?

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

```
#include<stdio.h>    
int main()
{
  char *p = NULL;
  char str[] = "How do you do!!!!!";
  p = &str;
  printf("String is:%s",p);
  p = "HELLO HOW ARE YOU";

  printf("String is:%s",p);
  printf("Hello");


  int a = 10;
  int *pa;
  pa = &a;
  printf("Contents of a is %d\n",a);
  printf("Contents of pa is %x\n", (int)pa);
  printf("Values of variable pointed to by pa is %d\n", *pa);

  return 0;
}
```

While referring to the above code :

```
p = &str;
printf("String is:%s",p);
```

p will display string stored.

```
pa = &a;
printf("Values of variable pointed to by pa is %d\n", *pa);
```

But here if i want to display value of `a=10` I will have to write `*pa`.

Why so ? What's the difference between the two ?

Why one show right when used `p` and other will show right when used `*pa`

In one case derefernce operator is used and in other it is not required

Comment: First of all, fix your horrible formatting.

Comment: The following issues need to be resolved: the title should reflect the problem you're having, and would be very similar to what you type into google if you were searching for an answer to your problem. Secondly I bet there are a few dupes of this around, but don't know the terms well enough to find them.

Comment: This might help understand: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2528318/1147772

Answer (score 5):

Read the basics of [`printf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) and the format specifiers.

- `%s` expects a "pointer" type (*to be exact, "pointer to the initial
  element of an array of character type"*)argument, so, we're passing pointer.
- `%d` expects an `int` as argument, so, we need to pass the *variable value*, i.e., de-reference the pointer.

Answer (score -3):

First of all the compiler should issue a diagnostic message at least for statement

```
p = &str;
```

because there is no implicit conversion between types `char *` (the type of p) and `char ( * )[19]` that is the type of expression `&str`

So you have to write simply

```
p = str;
```

The reason for that the printf prints the same string is because the value of expressions `&str` and `str` is the same.

To print a string you have to specify format specifier `%s` and corresponding argument shall be a pointer to char.

```
printf("String is:%s",p);
```

When you want to print a scalar value like an object of type int you have to specify it itself as an argument of printf
In this statement

```
printf("Values of variable pointed to by pa is %d\n", *pa);
```

expression `*pa` is indeed an object of type int.