# NSData from UInt8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, nsdata

I have recently found a source code in swift and I am trying to get it to objective-C. The one thing I was unable to understand is this:

```
var theData:UInt8!

theData = 3;
NSData(bytes: [theData] as [UInt8], length: 1)
```

Can anybody help me with the Obj-C equivalent?

Just to give you some context, I need to send UInt8 to a CoreBluetooth peripheral (CBPeripheral) as UInt8. Float or integer won't work because the data type would be too big.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you write the Swift code slightly simpler as

```
var theData : UInt8 = 3
let data = NSData(bytes: &theData, length: 1)
```

then it is relatively straight-forward to translate that to Objective-C:

```
uint8_t theData = 3;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&theData length:1];
```

For multiple bytes you would use an array

```
var theData : [UInt8] = [ 3, 4, 5 ]
let data = NSData(bytes: &theData, length: theData.count)
```

which translates to Objective-C as

```
uint8_t theData[] = { 3, 4, 5 };
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&theData length:sizeof(theData)];
```

(and you can omit the address-of operator in the last statement,
see for example [How come an array's address is equal to its value in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c)).

Comment: Ha! ... I was missing the &theData ... I am an idiot, but a happy one ... cheers buddy!

Answer (score 5):

In **Swift 3**

```
var myValue: UInt8 = 3 // This can't be let properties
let value = Data(bytes: &myValue, count: MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size)
```

Answer (score 3):

In Swift,

`Data` has a native `init` method.

```
// Foundation -> Data  

/// Creates a new instance of a collection containing the elements of a
/// sequence.
///
/// - Parameter elements: The sequence of elements for the new collection.
///   `elements` must be finite.
@inlinable public init<S>(_ elements: S) where S : Sequence, S.Element == UInt8

@available(swift 4.2)
@available(swift, deprecated: 5, message: "use `init(_:)` instead")
public init<S>(bytes elements: S) where S : Sequence, S.Element == UInt8
```

So, the following will work.

```
let values: [UInt8] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let data = Data(values)
```