# How to search for the number of times a word appears in a text file

Tags: c, string, io, strcmp

I'm trying to write a program that i have to enter a word from the keyboard and then it will check how much times appears in a text file using the strcmp() function. here is my code. i can write the word but when i enter the enter button the program stops. anyone can help me to figured out whats going wrong?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
char input[20];
char string[20];
int num = 0;


FILE *text;

printf("Enter a word:\n");
scanf_s("%s\n", &input);

fopen_s(&text, "C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\ConsoleApplication8\\text.txt", "r");

if (text == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to open file\n");
    return (-1);
}

while (!feof(text))
{
    fscanf_s(text, "%s", string);
    if (!strcmp(string, input));
    num++;
}

printf("we found the word %d times\n", num);

return 0;
}`
```

Comment: Remove the `\n` from `scanf_s()` call. Also, see: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: did it already but doesn't worked

Comment: for `scanf_s()` while scanning `char` or `char*` you need to send a 3rd argument to specify the buffer length see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx

Comment: Lose the semicolon in `if (!strcmp(string, input));`.

Comment: scanf is not suitable when learning C.  Avoid it like the plague.

Comment: @WilliamPursell - drop "when learning C" and we're in 100% agreement. :-)

Comment: @Bob Jarvis, I was going to write "once you've learned c, you won't need it", but didn't want to seem too extreme.  I truly don't understand why people teach it!

Answer (score 1):

*[From this `"C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\ ...` I concluded the compiler in use is MS-VC]*

Besides the wrong use of `feof()` as pointed out by *[MarianD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7023590/mariand)* in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449751/694576), there is the following ***fatal*** mistake:

This line misses the size of the buffer to scan into:

```
  fscanf_s(text, "%s", string);
```

It should be

```
  fscanf_s(text, "%s", string, (unsigned) sizeof string);
```

Same plus 1 issue here:

```
  scanf_s("%s\n", &input)
```

1. Pass `input`, not its address. `%s` expects a `char*` (to which `input` decays). Doing `&input` would in fact pass the same value, but use the wrong type, namely `char(*)[20]`, which would invoke UB.
2. Pass its size:

   ```
   scanf_s("%s\n", input, (unsigned) sizeof input)
   ```

From [`fscanf_s` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ybhk9kc.aspx):

> The main difference between the more secure functions (that have the _s suffix) and the other versions is that the more secure functions require the size in characters of each c, C, s, S, and [ type field to be passed as an argument immediately following the variable.
>
> [...]
>
> The size parameter is of type `unsigned`, not `size_t`.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
scanf_s("%s\n", &input);
```

by

```
scanf_s("%s\n", input);
```

Indeed input is already a char* and you are sending a `char (*)[20]`.

Comment: **No, you are wrong** (in spite the idea behind it is in general true). `input` and `&input` are in this case the same - see [How come an array's address is equal to its value in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2528328/7023590)

Comment: Hmm, maybe that's because you are not compiling with the same flags as me but if you try with -pedantic -Wall flag you'll get a warning.

Comment: It is only **warning** (incompatible pointer type) as compiler don't know anything about **using** this in the body of the called function (particularly if it will perform *pointer arithmetic* - which **is** different for `input` and `&input`). **Values** (= addresses) are the same, **behavior** is **in this case** the same, too, so **your answer has no chance to solve** the problem. (**I'am sorry** that you are not correct but is it not pleasurable to learn something new?)

Comment: @MarianD: Same value but wrong type, so using `&input` invokes UB by passing the wrong pointer type, namely `char(*)[20]` instead of `char*`.

Comment: Assuming MS-VC, this `scanf_s("%s\n", input);` is incomplete, to not say wrong.

Comment: I agree with you (2 times) but my point was that in this case it doesn't make a difference of behavior (and so it doesn't help the person who asked this question).