# How this is calculating size in c?

Tags: c

Can someone please explain why the following code successfully prints the length of `arr[]`?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,9,8,7};

  int size = *(&arr+1) - arr;    

  printf("%d\n",size);
}
```

I'm specifically interested in the memory layout behind these operations.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'how its working' more precise.

Comment: Think about how a pointer arithmetic is working and what `&arr+1` is really doing.

Comment: Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question.

Comment: What output did you get and what output do you expect?

Comment: @jhenderson2099 — it is an MCVE. It’s not very good (missing newline in output mainly), but it is an MCVE.

Comment: This answer might help you understand: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2528328/669576

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - When I originally reviewed the post, the only question was in the subject.  The answer to that question seemed could be researched.  The question has since been reworded.  Please note that with a -7 score, multiple people other than me agree that there are issues with this question.

Comment: @jhenderson2099: Looks pretty good to me now.

Comment: Generally doing things like this is a bad idea. Use `sizeof arr` to determine the size of an object, don't mess around with pointer arithmetic for that.

Comment: @jhenderson2099: I didn't say there weren't issues with the question.  I did say that it contained an MCVE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First and foremost**, please don't write code this way... `*(&arr + 1)` is **undefined behavior**...

---

**Note:** This answer assumes `sizeof(int) = 4`.

What is `arr`? It's an array of 9 ints

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(arr)); // 36 bytes
printf("%p\n", (void *)arr); // 0x7ffed90f48a0
```

What is `&arr`? It's a pointer to an array or ints = `int (*)[9]`

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(&arr)); // 8 bytes (the size of a pointer)
printf("%p\n", (void *)(&arr)); // 0x7ffed90f48a0
```

What is `&arr + 1`? Since this implies pointer arithmetic, the result is a pointer to the subsequent `int (*)[9]` in the memory (Notice the address gap of 0x24(36) bytes)

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(&arr + 1)); // 8 bytes (the size of a pointer)
printf("%p\n", (void *)(&arr + 1)); // 0x7ffed90f48c4
```

What is `*(&arr + 1)`? We dereference the pointer to the subsequent array `&arr + 1` and get a pointer to an array of ints, just like our original `arr`, only that this pointer points to some invalid memory location:

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(*(&arr + 1))); // 36 bytes
printf("%p\n", (void *)(*(&arr + 1))); // 0x7ffed90f48c4
```

**Conclusion**

`*(&arr + 1) - arr` performs an implicit pointer arithmetic subtraction between two int arrays (pretty much the same as subtracting `int *`).

Since we already saw that the difference is 36 bytes, and we use `int` units and `sizeof(int) = 4`, the result is 9.

Comment: [Here](https://ideone.com/MuPlH7) `sizeof(int (*)[9])` is giving `8`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @DanielTrugman The `sizeof` operator works in bytes (chars if we want to nitpick) whereas pointer arithmetic doesn't. Your reasoning is sound but your terminology is confusing.

Comment: I don't like it. `*(&arr + 1)` is UB. That's the end of it.

Comment: What do you want to say with `sizeof(int (*)[9])`? This is the size of a pointer, has nothing to do with the problem at hand. Maybe you wanted to talk about `sizeof(int [9])` ? But this will usually be `sizeof(int)*9`.

Comment: @DanielTrugman I understand that, but you are assuming that everyone who knows C, also knows C++ and can read your answer. Which is definitely not true.

Comment: The final note " *(&arr + 1) is undefined behavior" deserves to be first - and not a note.

Comment: @chux, I hear ya, moved the comment to the top :)

Answer (score 5):

The behaviour of `*(&arr+1)` is *undefined*:

`&arr` is of type `int (*)[9]` due to the address of operator being applied to `arr`, which is of type `int[9]` (Acknowledgements to Klas Lindbäck for pointing out that pointer decay does not occur here.)

`&arr + 1` is borderline invalid pointer arithmetic since you don't have an *array* of `int (*)[9]`. But you *are* allowed to set a pointer to one past a scalar, so all fine here.

But *deferencing* that is undefined. Don't be at all surprised if you compiler eats your cat.

Comment: It is correct, `&arr` gives you an array pointer to a single object (the array) and you are not allowed to point past that object. The rule that allows us to point one item past an array does not apply, if so the code should have been written as `(arr + 9)` which would have been well-defined. De-referencing the array pointer `*(&arr + 1)` is, arguably, de-referencing of an invalid array pointer.

Comment: “Borderline invalid” is an interesting concept. Isn’t almost every code snippet just a small change away from invalid. Is “0” borderline invalid since using it as a divisor has undefined behavior?

Comment: @Lundin: What do you mean the one-past rule does not apply? You do not mean `&arr+1` is undefined, do you? Do you mean that, although we can evaluate `&arr+1`, the one-past rule does not allow us to apply `*` to it? Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that int size is 2 bytes currently.

arr is stored at 65506 and when you do (&arr + 1) address of arr is incremented by 1 (not with an integer 1 an give you 65507), and give you next address where array ends. becuase arr is is a variable no matter of which type and how long when you increment it, it will take you to the end of variable.

Now, as i said above that int is 2 bytes long so the array of 9 will be 18 bytes long and arr+1 will give you 65506 + 18 = 65626

so, we have value of arr + 1 = 65524 and arr = 65506. i i know the anser will be 18, but as you used address of and references, it will return 9. for this you need to go deep inside dereferencing and address variables and also need to debug the stack and program for every itteration for better understanding.

By the way, you can also use another simple methods for doing this such as

```
   int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(a[0]);
```

Here the size of your total array, taht is 18 is devided by your first element's size. no doubt, every element present in array is of same type, same size; which is here int it will return 2 and 18 is divided by 2 and will give you 9 in simple and efficient way.