# reference of array address is the same as its address

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

If we reference an array, like

```
int array[10];
int *p = &array;
```

in GCC we have that `p == array`, or `p == *p`.

Beside the rationale explained in other answer (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c)), is that a standard and defined behaviur, or some specific implementation could generate different address?

edit:
to be clear the question is: is this in the C standard, and if it is, since when?

Comment: `p == array` or `p == *p` are mistakes in Standard C, it's a gcc extension to allow that

Comment: What is it about the answers that you find unsatisfactory?

Comment: @M.M find a source and make an answer, i will accept it

Comment: @jxh they explain WHY but not if it is STANDARD C and what standard.

Comment: The citations into the C standard is not really interesting. If you have a copy, look for the definition of an array. Then consider how `int x` differs from `int x[1]`.

Comment: @jxh is not *interesting*? then if you decide to use &array are you sure this is going to work across all compiler, or across compiler updates?
Plus side, if NOT a standard, and if tehre are different implementation, would not be *interesting* to learn their reasoning?
My question is clear and the answer should be "YES, SINCE Cxx" or "NO"

Comment: I only mean it is not interesting because there are two definitions: array, and address-of operator.