# why array index and address have the same value as string assigned to array?

Tags: c, arrays

I had written some code but it is giving me some strange result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{ 
    char r[]={"1dam"};
    printf("  %s \n  %s ",r,&r);
    return(0);
}
```

output

```
1dam
1dam
```

Comment: `r`, being an array, will already be passed as its address to `printf`. So taking its address as in `&r` has no use here.

Comment: "it is giving me some strange result" --> How is it strange to you? What did you expect?

Comment: Note that `printf("%s",&r);` is UB.  `"%s"` expects a _character pointer_, not a pointer to a character array.

Comment: The second parameter invokes undefined behaviour. On a modern toolchain/library you should get a warning. If not, enable warnings (you are supposed to enable and fix warnings before asking, btw.). Don't ignore warnings!

Answer (score 2):

The pointers have the same value (point to the same address) but have different types.

One (`r`) is `char *`, the other (`&r`) is `char (*)[5]` (pointer to array of 5 characters).  A good compiler will warn you that `%s` can't process `char (*)[5]`.  The address is the same, but add one to each and print the pointer value (`%p` and cast to `(void *)`) and you'll get different results.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{ 
    char r[]={"1dam"};
    printf("%s\n%s\n", r, &r);
    printf("%p : %p\n", (void *)r, (void *)&r);
    printf("%p : %p\n", (void *)(r + 1), (void *)(&r + 1));
    return(0);
}
```

Output (on a Mac running macOS 10.13.6 High Sierra, using GCC 8.2.0):

```
1dam
1dam
0x7ffeebe8648b : 0x7ffeebe8648b
0x7ffeebe8648c : 0x7ffeebe86490
```

I had to compile suppressing my normal options, which gave:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes pa31.c -o pa31
pa31.c: In function ‘main’:
pa31.c:6:22: error: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘char (*)[5]’ [-Werror=format=]
         printf("%s\n%s\n", r, &r);
                     ~^        ~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
$
```

Comment: looks like it's a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c but I'll let you confirm that.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Agreed — hence closed as a duplicate.  Thanks for pointing it out, though I'd noticed it as a duplicate from one of the links in the other answer and closed-as-duplicate just seconds before your comments.

Comment: good. Not a very common duplicate, though.

Answer (score 0):

The name of an array (in your case array `r`) usually evaluates to the address of the first element of the array, so `r` and `&r` have the same value (but different types, so `r + 1` and `&r + 1` will **not** be equal if the array is more than 1 element long).

If your array has been defined as `TYPE array[size]`, array name will decay to type `TYPE *`. Any increments/decrements operation on such variable will result in pointer moving in steps of `TYPE` bytes.

`&r` evaluates to the same address, but given the same definition, it creates a pointer of the type `TYPE (*)[size]` (pointer to an array of **size** **TYPE**) (refer [this](https://medium.com/@bartobri/untangling-complex-c-declarations-9b6a0cf88c96) untangling complex declarations in `C`) -- i.e., **it's a pointer to an array, not to a single element**. If you increment this pointer, it'll add the size of the entire array, not the size of a single element.

However, the same thing doesn't happen with a variable declared as `pointer` to `TYPE` (TYPE *ptr). You can run the program given below. In the program below, I have printed the addresses of `r`, `&r`, `ptr` and `&ptr`. You can see the address of `r` and `&r` is same (but they have different type). However, `ptr` and `&ptr` have different addresses (and they have different types as well. `ptr` is of type `char *` and `&ptr` is of type `char **`).

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c) question to understand the concept in detail.

For example, consider the program given below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{ 
    char r[] = "1dam";
    printf("  %s \n  %s \r\n",r, &r);

    char *ptr = r;
    printf( " Pointers: %p %p \r\n", ptr, &ptr);
    printf( " Array: %p %p \r\n", r, &r);
    return 0;
}
```

The  output of the program is:

```
1dam 
1dam 
Pointers: 0x7fff4d46cd50 0x7fff4d46cd48 
Array: 0x7fff4d46cd50 0x7fff4d46cd50
```

However, compiling the above code (on my `Linux` machine) issues a warning.

> test.c:7:9: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘char (*)[5]’ [-Wformat=]
>     printf("  %s \n  %s \r\n",r, &r);

Comment: Good catch on the x-ref to SO 2528328 (How come an array's address is equal to its value in C).