# About typecasting of an array to pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I want to understand where exactly in code an array gets converted to a pointer. For example:

```
void foo( int* pData, int len){}

int main(void){
    char data[] = "Hello world";

    foo( (int*)data, sizeof(data));

    return 0;
}
```

I know that an array decays to a pointer to the first element if it is assigned to a pointer. However in the example above, I typecast the array data to int* first before passing it in function and assigning it to a pointer. Does the conversion/decay to pointer occurs at the typecasting point ? If so, isn't it true to say that the typecasting operation has the same effect as using the assignment operator with respect to array conversion/decay? Also would sizeof(data) be equal to the address length or array length?

Thank you for help!

Comment: choose your language. C and C++ are not the same!

Comment: This won't compile. What is `int main{`?

Comment: sorry i corrected int main and yes it is C, i edited the tag.

Answer (score 1):

The conversion of arrays to pointers in C is spelled out in section 6.3.2.1p3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> Except  when  it  is  the  operand  of  the `sizeof` operator, the
>   `_Alignof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, or is a string 
>   literal  used  to  initialize  an  array, an expression  that  has
>   type "array of type" is converted to an expression with type "pointer
>   to type"  that  points to  the  initial  element  of  the  array 
>   object  and  is  not  an  lvalue.   If  the  array  object  has
>   register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

This means that the array is immediately converted to a pointer anywhere it is used *except* for the three cases listed above.

So applying the above to `(int*)data`, `data` is the operand of the typecast operator.  Since this operator is not one of the ones listed above, `data` in this expression is converted from `char [12]` to `char *`, then the cast converts the `char *` to an `int *`.

Also, as mentioned above, the array is **not** converted when passed to `sizeof`.  This means `sizeof(data)` evaluates to the size of `char [12]` which is 12.

Comment: Adding to @dbush, sizeof operator returns 12 here because data was initialized as an array in your example. That's the another inherent difference between arrays and pointers.

Comment: @Harveer - that's not quite true.   `data` is initialised using a string literal.  A string literal is not actually an array - but it is represented in memory as a statically allocated array as far as your program is concerned.   And string literals are a special case in the language - it is possible to do `const char *pointer = "Hello World";`  but not `const char *pointer2 = {'a', 'b'};`

Comment: The operand of `sizeof` in `sizeof(data)` is not `data`; it is `(data)`. A parenthesized expression is an expression, so the rule quoted in this answer would say that `data` is converted to a pointer to its first element. There are separate rules in the specification of a parenthesized expression that cover this.

Comment: @Peter No, it's an array and is different than a pointer pointing to a string literal. Underneath, compiler would expand this "char data[]" to have the size equal to the string it is initialized with. see here: https://godbolt.org/z/0cmJPI. Here, compiler knows that the size of an array by looking at it's string literal size. You can try changing that to provide a static size of 3 and you will still see the same assembly. I hope this helps.

Comment: @Harveer - you're missing my point.   I'm not suggesting a string literal is a pointer.

Comment: Probably I am not getting your point. But this is not a string literal. String literals are immutable as they get allocated in read-only memory of the process. But this array above is mutable.

Comment: @dbush is it correct to say that the array conversion is always evaluated and is not a one time operation done at the first opportunity the condition is valid for an array conversion?

Comment: @Harveer: Whether string literals are put in read-only memory is up to the C implementation. The C standard does not require it.

Comment: Also, when we access an element using the expression data[2] for element 2 for example, data will be converted to pointer according to the rule above. Can someone confirm this is true please?

Comment: @user12100664 yes this is true.  `data[2]` is exactly the same as `*(data + 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Outwith the declaration, you can consider `data` to be equivalent to a pointer to the start of the array, but with the following exceptions:

- `sizeof(data)` will give you the size of the array in bytes.
- `_Alignof(data)` will be the same as `_Alignof(*data)` (and both give you the alignment of the type of the array elements)
- `&data` has the same value as just `data`, but have a type of `char (*)[sizeof(data]` so arithmetic will use the full size of the array. Eg `&data+1` will give you the address after the whole array rather than the address of the second element. See [How come an array's address is equal to its value in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c)
- you can't change it's value (ie in this sense it is equivalent to a `char *const`).

When you call your function, you are taking the value of `data` (ie the address of the start of the array) and typecasting to an `int *`. The resulting `int *` behaves like any other `int *` and the exceptions don't apply, this is the 'decay'.

Comment: &data has the type: ”char (*)[]” and does not have the same value as data.

Comment: @Fredrick, definitely the same value, both are the address of the array. Good catch on the type though. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c

Comment: `_Alignof(data)` is not a standard C expression. The C standard only defines `_Alignof` applied to a type name, not to an expression. It was a mistake in the standard to include mention of `_Alignof` in discussing the automatic array conversion, and that mistake was corrected in C 2018.