# Correct usage of MPI_Send and MPI_Recv

Tags: c++, mpi

I am working on a simple program in C++ that uses MPI to communicate between two processes. If I want to send an array to another process, the `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` functions expect a pointer to the said array:

```
int MPI_Send(void *buf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int dest, int tag, MPI_Comm comm)
int MPI_Recv(void *buf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int source, int tag, MPI_Comm comm, MPI_Status *status);
```

In an [online tutorial](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/349/introduction-to-mpi/blocking-communications---exercise) I saw the following usage of MPI_Send and MPI_Recv:

```
int values[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
MPI_Send(values, 5, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

and

```
int values[10];
MPI_Recv(&values, 10, MPI_INT, 3, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

Why does the tutorial use in one case only `values` and in the other case also the address operator `&values`?

I wrote a program to send and receive arrays between two processes and it seems that it works with and without the address operator. Why is this the case? I'm certainly mistaken in my thinking. Can you help me find my mistake?

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    // Reading size and rank
    int size, rank;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    // For every process create array 
    double array[2];
    if (rank == 0) {
        array[0] = 0.1;
        array[1] = 0.2;
    } else {
        if (rank == 1) {
            array[0] = 1.1;
            array[1] = 1.2;
        }
    }

    // Send and receive
    double other_array[2];
    if (rank == 0) {
        MPI_Send(&array, 2, MPI_DOUBLE, 1, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Recv(&other_array, 2, MPI_DOUBLE, 1, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        // OR
        // MPI_Send(array, 2, MPI_DOUBLE, 1, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        // MPI_Recv(other_array, 2, MPI_DOUBLE, 1, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        std::cout << rank << " " << other_array[0] << " " << other_array[1] << std::endl;
    } else {
        MPI_Recv(&other_array, 2, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        MPI_Send(&array, 2, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        // OR
        // MPI_Recv(other_array, 2, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        // MPI_Send(array, 2, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        std::cout << rank << " " << other_array[0] << " " << other_array[1] << std::endl;
    }

    // Finalisation
    int MPI_Finalize(); 

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled and ran the programm using

`mpic++ -O -Wall main.cpp -o main`
`mpirun -np 2 ./main`

Comment: `&` is likely a typo and you do not need it.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet But why do both versions work then? Why does the compiler not throw an error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How come an array's address is equal to its value in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c)