# Are gcc's dynamically-sized arrays effectively identical to standard arrays after declaration?

Tags: c++, arrays, gcc, variable-length-array

In standard C and C++ [the address of an array is the array itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2528318/1270789), and `sizeof` returns the size of the array, not the pointer. However, does `gcc`'s extension of dynamically-sized arrays offer the same guarantee?

[I tried this simple code](https://onlinegdb.com/rJi2njCeL):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    char foo[200];
    char bar[atoi(argv[1])];
    char *wibble = foo;

    printf("%p, %p, %lu, %p, %p, %lu, %p, %p, %lu\n",
           foo, &foo, sizeof(foo), bar, &bar, sizeof(bar), wibble, &wibble, sizeof(wibble));

    return 0;
}
```

The output is as I hoped, indicating equivalence:

```
0x7ffc7dd132e0, 0x7ffc7dd132e0, 200, 0x7ffc7dd131e0, 0x7ffc7dd131e0, 200, 0x7ffc7dd132e0, 0x7ffc7dd132c8, 8
```

However, is this equivalence guaranteed by `gcc`? Are there any times where using a dynamically-sized instead of a statically-sized array will result in different program behaviour?

<sup>※ Note I'm interested in if it works, not how to write it better using `std::vector`, etc</sup>

Comment: Why would you expect a non-standard language extension to provide strict guarantees on this behavior? It's hard to "language lawyer" things that aren't part of the language.

Comment: "*The output is as I hoped, indicating equivalence:*" Is it? What does the compiled code look like? Does it change if you pass different numbers as arguments? What happens if you use `sizeof(bar)` in a constant expression?

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, using `sizeof(bar)` in a constant expression is obviously going to be problematic; that's why I'm asking the question! @ShadowRanger I would hope that the developers thought through the issues, not just slapped in a hack to support the declaration.

Comment: @KenY-N: If you know that they're not equivalent... why are you asking if they're equivalent?

Comment: @NicolBolas I only realised they are not equivalent when you posed your question! Where else might they differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from the [ISO C99 doc](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), page 80:

> The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which
>   may be an
>       expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of
>       the operand. The result is an integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length 
>       array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated 
>       and the result is an integer constant.

So the answer to your first question is that it's guaranteed by the C99 standard, which gcc presumably follows.

As for whether there are times it'll behave differently from a statically sized array well...not if you're using them sanely.

While I can't find record of this in ISO C99, it appears that gcc always puts a VLA on the stack - which makes sense because it's essentially an alloca(), and is intended to go out of scope at the end of the block. Used sanely, there should never be any difference between how a dynamically sized array behaves and how a statically sized array behaves. Used **insanely** however, yes there could be extreme corner cases for exploitation (or other hacky) behavior where a person doing exploitation might be happy to discover you're using one over the other.

Regardless, you can probably feel comfortable using whichever one you feel comfortable with. Usually, (for one or two reasons of varying justifiability) programmers prefer malloc over stack allocations.

Comment: Ahh, I had forgotten that [VLAs are official C from C99 onwards (but not C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097/1270789), so there has to be official language for their validity, and I suppose for C++ the `g++` people  decided they cannot be used (for example (just guessing here!)) in templates when the size cannot be determined at compile time, or similar.