# Why is it possible to pass a double pointer (address of address) to scanf?

Tags: c, scanf

This simple code is what I would expect:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char input[20];
    printf("enter a string: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", input);
    printf("input: %s\n", input);
}
```

where `input` is `(char*)[20]`. But then why can I pass this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char input[20];
    printf("enter a string: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", &input);
    printf("input: %s\n", input);
}
```

and it still compiles and runs? The argument `&input` passed should be `(char**)[20]` which should not be correct, yet it runs. Why?

Comment: scanf doesn't perform compile time type checking, you could pass anything you want and it would compile. Your compiler will warn you about this though with the right flags.

Comment: It's `char(*)[20]`, not `(char**)[20]`. But solid question otherwise, assuming that small difference doesn't make the question moot for you.

Comment: @Peter ok, but it does not only compile, it even runs. So it has no problem in runtime

Comment: @milanHrabos That can also be explained: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica ok, so to clarify (for myself), the `input` is type `(char*)` and `&input` is `char(*)[20]`? Because I thought the second one as double address since the array is already address, and you take an address of it

Comment: Arrays and pointers aren't the same.

Comment: @milanHrabos - Arrays are not pointers. They are an aggregate object type, and don't contain an address as a value. When you deal with arrays, they *usually* get converted to a pointer unto their first element (cheaper to pass around normally, so a design choice). But, when you take their address, you don't get a double pointer, you get a pointer to the array (which is why the type is composed of `char[20]`, the size information is part of the array type).

Comment: @milanHrabos Another way to look at it:  pointers are variables that *hold* an address.  Arrays are chunks of memory that *have* an address and arrays are passed to functions by passing that address, which is why they look like pointers in function calls.

Comment: @milanHrabos Why did you delete the question? after I have posted an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your code, the expression `input` (when used as an argument to `scanf`) will evaluate (i.e. [*decay*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/509868)) to the address of the first element of the 20-character array and the expression `&input` will evaluate to the address of the array itself - which will be the same, *in this case*. This can be demonstrated by adding a line like the following to your code:

```c
    printf("%p %p\n", (void*)(input), (void*)(&input)); // Print the two addresses - SAME!
```

Thus, your call to `scanf` will actually pass the correct value (the address of the input buffer).

However, a good compiler will warn you about the incompatible pointer type; for example, clang-cl generates this:

```
warning : format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type
'char (*)[20]' [-Wformat]
```

It is, of course, up to you whether you want to address the warning or ignore it; but, in more complex code, such 'mistakes' can cause run-time errors that are very difficult to track down.

Comment: And how does `scanf` function work? Because if it takes my `&input` of type `char(*)[20]`, and the scanf will put another char by `input + 1`, then the arithmetic is wrong, because it won't move one character further, but 20 characters further. So still, the two different argument (input, &input), depict different types. So the scanf has to handle it somehow. But how? Does it cast it to (char*) type anyway?

Comment: @milanHrabos Internally, the `scanf` function just recieves arguments it takes as addresses; it determines the types of those pointers according to the corresponding format specifiers - in your case, a `%s` tells it it's a `char*` type (or *should* be). The C language allows you to *lie* to a function call; but, just because you can, doesn't mean that you should.

Comment: Ok, so as I said, it will treat as `char*` anyway. No meter if I pass `char(*)[20]`, it still treats it as `char*` becuase of `%s` in the first argument right?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah. In your case, there's no problem. However, if you pass an `int*` argument when the format specifier expects a `double*` (for example), then the `scanf` *could* cause memory corruption.

Comment: @milanHrabos "No meter if I pass `char(*)[20]`, it still treats it as `char*` becuase of `%s` in the first argument right?" No. Well your system and (almost) any other real world system this statement is true, but not according to the c standard. A machine can use 2 different ways to store a pointer `char *` and `char (*)[20]`, in which case it would cause UB.