# What Happens in Scanf When We Using & Operator?

Tags: c++, c

When we using '&' operator in scanf, do we scan address or exact value in that adress? For instance i don't understand how this 2 code give to us same result.

CODE 1

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){ 
    int arr[6], i, sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<6;i++){
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        sum+=arr[i];
    }
    printf("%d", sum);  
}
```

CODE 2

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){ 
    int arr[6], i, sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<6;i++){
        scanf("%d", (arr+i));
        sum+=*(arr+i);
    }
    printf("%d", sum);  
}
```

Comment: This is not related to scanf. Note that &arr and arr give the same value. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2528328/13559733

Comment: The expression `X[Y]` is equivalent to `*(X+Y)` then `&arr[i]` becomes `&*(arr+i)` which is the same as `arr+i`. (Does that mean that `X[Y]` can also be written as `Y[X]`? Yes.)

Comment: `arr[i]` is equivalent to `*(arr+i)`, so `&arr[i]` is equivalent to `&*(arr+i)`. The `&` and `*` sort of cancel out, so `&arr[i]` is equivalent to `(arr+i)`. In both cases, a pointer to the *i*-th element of `arr` is passed to `scanf`.

Comment: @AleksanderBobiński when passed to functions. as expressions they are different. `&arr` is an `int*` expression, whereas `arr` is an `int[6]` expression.

Comment: `scanf` "scans" stdin; the address argument is the _destination_  for the converted input, not what is being "scanned".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf()` requires you to pass it the *address* of each variable that you want it to write parsed values to. The `&` operator returns those addresses.

In your examples, `&arr[i]` and `(arr+i)` both represent the same address of the `i`'th array element, and also `arr[i]` and `*(arr+i)` both represent accesses to that same element's stored value.

Answer (score 0):

`&` is the address-of operator, i.e. given an object, it gives you a pointer to that object.

Along with ordinary arithemetic, `operator+` applied to a (pointer, integer) pair gives you a pointer to another element of the same array (so long as there are such elements) or a pointer one past the end of the array (if the value is exactly distance to the end) or undefined behaviour (if you would be out of range).

`a[i]` is defined as `*(a + i)`. It dereferences the calculated pointer.

Putting that together, `arr + i` is an `int*` expression, whereas `arr[i]` is an `int` expression. As we need an `int*` for `scanf`, `&` is used to get one.

Answer (score 0):

From the C Standard (6.5.2.1 Array subscripting)

> 2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
> is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
> definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to
> (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
> binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer
> to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer,
> E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).

So the expression `&arr[i]` is equivalent to `&( *( arr + i ) )`. The operators `*` and `&` applied to the expression `arr + i` sequentially may be omitted and you will get that `&arr[i]` is equivalent tp `arr + i`. The both expressions are pointers to the `i-th` element of the array `arr`.