# Why the addres of an array name and the address he points to is the same?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

that's my first question on stackoverflow.
I was reflecting on how arrays and names of arrays work and i got a doubt.
I'm wondering why the address of an array name, and the address that he points to is the same.
Moreover, why if i try to extrat the value at the addres pointed he returns me 0x1 and not the address itself.

Thats the code, thanks to anyone who answers.

```
int x[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
int y;

printf("%p %p\n", &x, x);
printf("%p %p\n", &x[0], x);
printf("%p %p", x[0], *x);

return 0;
```

Thats the output on CodeChef:

0x7ffc7bfa3a70 0x7ffc7bfa3a70n
0x7ffc7bfa3a70 0x7ffc7bfa3a70
0x1 0x1

Comment: An array is just a fixed size block of memory and a pointer to the array is a pointer to the location where this memory block starts. And the first element of the array is of course also residing at this position, so a pointer to an array is also a pointer to it's first element.

Comment: `n` is not a hex digit. A possible typo?

Comment: But why the address where the name is located at, and the address that he points to are tha same?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How come an array's address is equal to its value in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c)

Comment: Thx to Alexander Guyer