# A pointer to an address of an array

Tags: arrays, c

Why does this code output: `1` ≡ `arr[0]` and not `&arr[0]`?

My assumption is that after the assignment, `ptr` holds the address of `&arr`, which is a pointer to the first element of `arr` or `arr[0]`.

So dereferencing the `ptr` should yield the value stored at that address, which is the memory location of the first element.

```cpp
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int arr[] = { 1 };
    int* ptr = &arr;
    printf("%d\n", *ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int* ptr = &arr;` - this is incompatible pointer assignment. `&arr` is of type `(int*)[1]` - that is a pointer to an array. It just happens that the value of it is the same as `&arr[0]`. So when you dereference `ptr` which has this value, you are getting the value of `arr[0]`

Comment: Learn to love compiler warnings, they are your friends. The code you have created will produce a warning on any sane compiler.

Comment: gcc reports `int (*)[1]` in the warning. Is  `(int*)[1]` the same? I believe not. The parens make the star mean the array not the int, so rather `int (*[])`

Comment: The code will produce an error on any correctly-configured compiler ; if you don't see this then I suggest changing settings

Comment: `(int*)[1]` is a syntax error; the type of `&arr` is `int(*)[1]`.. The parentheses serve to prevent the token sequence `int *` being parsed as *type-name*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things...

First, `a` doesn't store the location of `a[0]`.  There is no object `a` that is separate from the array element `a[0]`.  Basically what you have in memory is

```
Address        
-------       +------+ 
 0x1000    a: | 0x01 | a[0]
              +------+
```

In other words, the address of an array is the same as the address of its first element.

Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, the *expression* `a` will be converted ("decay") from type "1-element array of `int`" (`int [1]`) to "pointer to `int`" (`int *`) and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element in the array.

This means that the expressions `&a`, `a`, and `&a[0]` all yield the same address value; it's just the *types* of the expressions are different:

```
Expression     Type        Decays to    
----------     ----        ---------
        &a     int (*)[1]
         a     int [1]     int *
     &a[0]     int *
```

Which brings us to this line:

```
int* ptr = &arr; // int * = int (*)[1] - assignment of incompatible types
```

The compiler *should* have yelled at you about that line.  You may want to dial up the warning level.

Comment: There are other expressions where arrays don't decay aside from `sizeof` and `&`. For example, `_Alignof`.

Answer (score 1):

I added some print statements to your code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int arr[] = { 1 };
    int *ptr = (int *)arr;
    printf("%p\n", (void *)arr);
    printf("%p\n", (void *)&arr);
    printf("%p\n", (void *)&arr[0]);
    printf("%p\n", (void *)ptr);
    printf("%p\n", (void *)&ptr);
    printf("%d\n", *ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

It prints:

```
0x7ffe3fe37aa4
0x7ffe3fe37aa4
0x7ffe3fe37aa4
0x7ffe3fe37aa4
0x7ffe3fe37a98
1
```

Which means `arr` and `ptr` are on the stack: `ptr` is at `0x7ffe3fe37a98` and has the value `0x7ffe3fe37aa4`, which is where the `arr` is stored.

Note that `arr` and `&arr` have the same value. See this question: [How come an array's address is equal to its value in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c)

> My assumption is that after the assignment, `ptr` holds the address of `&arr`, which is a pointer to the first element of arr or arr[0].

That is correct.

> So dereferencing the ptr should yield the value stored at that address

Also correct.

> which is the memory location of the first element.

No. Since `ptr` is pointing to the first element, dereferencing yields the first element, which is 1.