# Is there any difference in passing &arr(address of entire block) or just passing name of array (address of first element)?

Tags: c++, c, embedded

```
void func1(int* ptr)
{
    printf("func1 :%d\n",++ptr);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[4] = {0,1,2,3};
    printf("Addr enter code here`f arr: %d\n",arr);
    func1(arr);  // first way:
    func1(&arr); // second way: How this will be different from func1(arr). 
}
```

[image: Image showing code run]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  *Images* of code are not really helpful - please paste the actual text of the code you wish to ask about.

Comment: Please use one of the the C or C++ tags - they are different languages.

Comment: Sure, will take care, By the way this was just an example to put my question, it holds for c++ too.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How come an array's address is equal to its value in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between `&arr` and `arr` is that the type of former is a pointer to an array `int (*)[4]`, and the type of latter is an array `int[4]` which can decay to pointer to the first element `int*`. Both the pointer to the array, and the decayed pointer to the first element point to the same address because the first byte of the array is also the first byte of the first element of the array.

The difference between `func1(&arr)` and `func1(arr)` is that former is ill-formed because `int (*)[4]` doesn't implicitly convert to `int*`. In order to be able to call `func1(&arr)`, you would have to accept a pointer of correct type:

```
void func1(int (*ptr)[4])
```

---

> ```
> printf("func1 :%d\n",++ptr);
> printf("Addr enter code here`f arr: %d\n",arr);
> ```

Both of these calls result in undefined behaviour. The type of the variadic argument must match the type required by the format specifier. You used the format specifier `%d` which requires the argument to be of type `int` (or similar). The type of the (decayed) argument here is `int*` which isn't `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays decay to pointer. Any of those pointers reference the same address in memory. The difference is in the type of this pointer.

```
int arr[5];
```

1. `arr` and `&arr[0]` have type **pointer to int** (`int *`)
2. `&arr` has type of **pointer to five elements integer array** ( `int (*)[5]`)

Comment: Will it make a difference if inside function I receive it as pointer to int i.e void func (int * ptr)

Comment: @NavneetKumar, `int*` and `int(*)[5]` are incompatible types, UB is invoked assuming that the compiler actually compiler this code without an error

Answer (score 1):

We have a function named `func1` that accepts a *pointer to an `int`* that is, its parameter is `int*`. Now lets see what is happening in each of the cases.

##### Case I

In this case we have `func1(arr);`

Here the variable `arr` is an *array of size 4 with elements of type `int`* (which is `int [4]`) but it **decays** to a *pointer to the first element*(which is `int*`) due to **type decay**.

So when you wrote,

```
func1(arr);
```

essentially you're passing an `int*` as an **argument** which **matches** with the type of the function **parameter**.

##### Case II

In this case we have `func1(&arr);`

Here `&arr` means a *pointer to an array of size 4 with elements of type `int`*.(which is `int (*)[4]`).

Now when you wrote,

```
func1(&arr);
```

essentially you're passing an `int (*)[4]` as an **argument** to the function `func1`. But note that the **parameter** of `func1` is of type `int*`. So there is **mismatch** in type of argument and parameter.

Now in the screenshot you posted, the program seems to be compiling and executed successfully. But note that since in the second case there is **mismatch** in argument and parmeter type you will get **undefined behavior**.

> Undefined behavior means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely** on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>