# Why pass by reference works also without '&'?

Tags: c

I'm checking my code currently for errors and found that I forgot to use '&' when I'm passing an array as a parameter to a function that I modify then.

I'm thinking that is because it's an array of chars, I'm already passing its address, even without the '&', but I couldn't validate it anywhere.

function prototype:

```
void removeWhiteChats(char *s);
```

Here's an example:

```
char p[] = "1 2 3     4 56";
removeWhiteChars(p);
print("%s,p);

Output: "123456";
```

and this works as well:

```
char p[] = "1 2 3     4 56";
removeWhiteChars(&p);
print("%s,p);

Output: "123456";
```

Comment: *"I'm passing an array as a parameter to a function"* No, you are passing a pointer, by value.

Comment: See also [How come an array's address is equal to its value in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c): You're passing the same address in both cases. Your function signature is `char*`, forcing the correct indexing.

Comment: C doesn't support pass by reference, what you are passing is a pointer variable.

Comment: `&p` is a pointer to an array. `p` becomes a pointer to the first element of the array.  They have the same value but different types.

Comment: @RinkeshP: In C, “pass by reference” means passing a reference manually, that is, providing a called function access to an object by passing a pointer to it. That is the terminology that was used in the past and that is still used, and the C standard says that a pointer provides a reference. In C++, a new feature was invented that provided a built-in automatic reference, and people discussing C++ use “reference” to mean that feature. That new use in the context of C++ does not change the meaning of “reference” when discussing C code. “Passing by reference” in C means passing a pointer.