# Why can an array used in fread/fwrite in a position of a buffer be written with or without & and yield the same result?

Tags: c, pointers, cs50, implicit-conversion, void-pointers

Why do these yield the same result?

```
uint8_t header[HEADER_SIZE];
fread(&header, sizeof(uint8_t), HEADER_SIZE, input);
fwrite(&header, sizeof(uint8_t), HEADER_SIZE, output);
```

```
uint8_t header[HEADER_SIZE];
fread(header, sizeof(uint8_t), HEADER_SIZE, input);
fwrite(header, sizeof(uint8_t), HEADER_SIZE, output);
```

In the first version, would the `&` not give access just to the location of the array, and not the array itself like in the second version? Were it a single valuable I understand why an `&` would be used, but I assumed an array is itself a "pointer", generally speaking, so there would be no reason to get its address again? Is it just redundancy in that case?

Comment: [How come an array's address is equal to its value in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2528318)

Comment: What is the difference between "the location of the array" and "the array itself"?

Comment: I did think there would be no difference but I wasn't exactly sure. That is however why I don't understand why some choose to put & in front of the array name

Comment: Adding to the existing answers: an array name like `header` by itself usually means the same as `&header[0]`.

Comment: @Dharmapala maybe to make the code clearer, make it explicit that an address is being passed?  To make passing array arguments consistent with every other type?   Sometimes, I hate C:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `fread` is declared the following way

```
size_t fread(void * restrict ptr, size_t size, 
             size_t nmemb, 
             FILE * restrict stream);
```

Its first parameter has the unqualified type `void *` (actually the parameter type is the qualified type `void * restrict`) . A pointer to object of any type may be assigned to a pointer of the type `void *`.

The expression `&header` has the pointer type `uint8_t ( * )[HEADER_SIZE]` and yields the initial address of the extent of memory occupied by the array,

The expression `header` used as an argument of a call of `fread` is implicitly converted to a pointer of the type `uint8_t *` and yields the same initial address of the extent of memory occupied by the array.

Thus these calls

```
fread(&header, sizeof(uint8_t), HEADER_SIZE, input);
fwrite(header, sizeof(uint8_t), HEADER_SIZE, output);
```

are equivalent in sense that the function `fread` gets the same values for its parameters.

Consider the following simple demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char s[6] = "Hello";

    printf( "The value of the expression  s is %p\n", ( void * )s );
    printf( "The value of the expression &s is %p\n", ( void * )&s );
}
```

The program output might look like

```
The value of the expression  s is 0x7fffa4577a2a
The value of the expression &s is 0x7fffa4577a2a
```

As you can see the both outputted values are equal each other though in the first call the used argument expression has the type `char *` while in the second case the used argument expression has the type `char ( * )[6]`.

However if you will write for example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char s[6] = "Hello";

    printf( "%s\n", s );
    printf( "%s\n", &s );
}
```

then the compiler can issue a message for the second call of `printf` that the function expects an argument of the type `char *` instead of the type `char ( * )[6]` though the both values of the expressions are equal each other.

Answer (score 1):

`header` is an array of `char`. Passing an array as an argument effectively passes a pointer to its first element, `fread` and `fwrite` accept pointers to `void` as their first argument so `fread(header, sizeof(uint8_t), HEADER_SIZE, input);` is fine although for consistency with the array definition it would be safer to write:

```
    fread(header, sizeof(*header), HEADER_SIZE, input);
```

`&header` has a different type: pointer to one or more arrays of `HEADER_SIZE` characters (`uint8_t (*)[HEADER_SIZE]`). Since `fread` accepts any kind of pointer, the compiler will accept the call `fread(&header, sizeof(uint8_t), HEADER_SIZE, input);` without a warning.

Because `header` and `&header` have the same address, `fread` will behave as expected, albeit this behavior is not guaranteed by the C Standard. Note however that if `header` was a pointer to `char`, passing `&header` would produce a very different result, undefined behavior indeed as the value of the pointer would be overwritten and probably many more bytes beyond...