# Array and pointer (something like &arr)

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int *a, *b,*c,**d;
    int arr[10]={0};
    a=arr;
    b=&arr;//is this true?why?
    c=&arr[0];
    d=&a;
    printf("%p,%p,%p,%p",a,b,c,d);
    return 0;
}
```

Does `&arr` something point to the first address of the array?

Is `b=&arr;` true?

What's the difference between `arr` and `&arr`?

Comment: Fyi, `&arr` isn't `int*`, it is `int (*)[10]` so `b = &arr` should pop a type warning.  And `&anything` returns the address of `anything`, so long as it is a legal language context to do so, with the result being a pointer-to-type, where 'type' is the type of object being addressed. The *values* of the address in all three contexts may be the same, but the *type* can be different, and if you think it doesn't matter, google *pointer arithmetic*.

Comment: The address of an array is the address of the first element. So while `arr` and `&arr` return the same address, as @WhozCraig explains, they are different in type. When referenced, an array is converted to pointer to type with the address of the first element [C18 Standard - 6.3.2.1 (3)](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2596.pdf)

Comment: For an exercise, output `printf ("arr     : %p\narr + 1 : %p\n&arr + 1: %p\n", (void*)arr, (void*)(arr + 1), (void*)(&arr + 1));` How far is `arr + 1` from `arr`? How far is `&arr + 1` from `arr`?

Comment: The question was editd to change from `int *b` to `int (*b)[10]` after the first answer was posted.  This is NOT allowed.  It wasn't the OP who changed that.  The `<studio.h>` to `<stdio.h>` spelling change is far less serious in most respects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How come an array's address is equal to its value in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

> Does `&arr` something point to the first address of the array?

`&arr` is pointer to whole array of `10` integers and not the pointer to first element of the array.

> Is `b=&arr;` true?

No, given `int *b`, then `b=&arr;` is an incompatible pointer type assignment because the type of `&arr` is `int (*)[10]` whereas the type of `b` is `int *`.  (If the definition is `int (*b)[10]`, there is no problem.)

> what is the difference between `arr` and `&arr`?

The `arr`, when used in a statement, will be converted to pointer to first element of array (there are few [exceptions](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) to this rule). The type of `arr` is `int *` and it is equivalent to `&arr[0]`<sup>1)</sup> (i.e. both are pointer to first element of array).

The `&arr` is pointer to the whole array (it's type is `int (*)[10]`).

The address of an array (`&arr`) and address of first element of an array (`arr` or `&arr[0]`) is numerically same though their type is different. That means, if we add `1` to them there results will be different (provided that the array size is greater than `1`). `arr + 1` result in pointer to `2`<sup>nd</sup> element whereas `&arr + 1` result in pointer after `10` elements of array `arr`.

Demonstration:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int arr[10];

    printf ("arr - %p\n", (void *)arr);
    printf ("&arr - %p\n", (void *)&arr);

    printf ("arr + 1 - %p\n", (void *)(arr + 1));
    printf ("&arr + 1 - %p\n", (void *)(&arr + 1));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out
arr - 0x7ff7bec77950
&arr - 0x7ff7bec77950
arr + 1 - 0x7ff7bec77954
&arr + 1 - 0x7ff7bec77978
```

Also, when using the format specifier `%p` in `printf()`, the corresponding argument('s) should be type casted to `(void *)`.

---

1). From C11 Standards#6.5.2.1

> The definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2)))..

Hence,

```
arr -> (arr + 0) -> &( *(arr + 0) ) -> &arr[0]
```

Comment: Always good to add that *type controls pointer arithmetic*. So while `arr + 1` points to the 2nd element of the array, `&arr + 1` points to the next `10` element array after `arr` (the address 1 past the end of `arr`).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Included your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: If I could vote twice I would, good answer.