# Why *(arr+1) brings the same value as arr+1 in multi-dimensional arrays?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have a doubt about multi-dimensional arrays and pointers notation, as below.

```
int arr[2][4] = {{1,2,3,4}, {5,6,7,8}};
printf("%d\n", (arr+1));
printf("%d\n", *(arr+1));
```

Why in both `printf()` calls, the result printed is the same? Both bring the addresses of the second array inside of the `arr`.
The first one I understand because `arr` is a memory address and so, adding 1 to it moves the pointer ahead by (the size of the inner array * size of integer).
But for the second one I am confused because if I put `*` before `(arr+1)`, shoudn't it be the value on the address of `(arr+1)`?

Comment: FYI: printing an address with `"%d"` invokes UB.

Comment: The code presented is not valid C.  Putting a data type, maybe `int`, in front of `arr[2][4]` would fix the worst problem by making that into a declaration.

Comment: With additional useful related info in [How come an array's address is equal to its value in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2528318/364696) and [What is array to pointer decay?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/364696).

Comment: @Filipe Andrade, "result printed in the screen is the same" --> technically the 2 pointers do not need to be the _same_ bit pattern, just _equivalent_ pointers - once converted to `void *`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(arr)` points to the first memory address of the `2 * 4` array, i.e., `arr[0][0]`.
`(arr+1)` points to the 2nd 1-D array comprising `arr`, i.e., it points to the **array** `arr[1]`.

Now, `*(arr+1)` is basically the address of the first element of the 2nd 1-D array comprising `arr`, i.e., it points to the **element** `arr[1][0]`.

If you know pointers well, `arr[1]` is the same address as `arr[1][0]`.

You can confirm that by checking `**(arr+1)`, which will output `5` in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Values are the same, but types are different: `int(*)[4]` (pointer to array of 4 ints) vs `int *` (pointer to int, but before the implicit conversion caused by passing it to a function it was `int[4]`, an array of 4 ints).

Those two values are `&arr[1]` and `&arr[1][0]` respectively. The first subarray and its first element have the same address.

Comment: ... and this is a many-times-over dupe, but making this comment is all I'm going to do about it because I am presently refraining from all community moderation actions.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Can you give me a good dupe link?

Answer (score 0):

`arr + 1` is the address of a block of `4` items.
`*(arr + 1)` is the address of `1` item.

Comment: Wrong `arr+1` is just `&arr[1]`.