# FFI: how to pass pointers in C to C functions?

Tags: c, ffi, libffi

I am struggling with `libffi` (Function Foreign Interface library), probably, due to the lack of C experience. I have the following program that calls a function `my_func` dynamically using `libffi`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ffi.h>

unsigned my_func(double a, double b, double *res) {
    res[0] = a + b;
    res[1] = a - b;

    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ffi_cif cif;
    ffi_type *arg_types[3] = {
        &ffi_type_double,
        &ffi_type_double,
        &ffi_type_pointer
    };
    ffi_type *rettype = &ffi_type_uint;

    if (ffi_prep_cif(&cif, FFI_DEFAULT_ABI, 2, rettype, arg_types) != FFI_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ffi_prep_cif is not successful\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    double a = 3.0;
    double b = 2.0;
    double res[2] = {99.0, 15.0};
    void *arg_values[3] = {
        &a,
        &b,
        res
    };

    unsigned status;
    ffi_call(&cif, FFI_FN(my_func), &status, arg_values);

    printf("Function return status code %u\n", status);
    printf("Values in res array: \n");
    printf("[0] = %f\n", res[0]);
    printf("[1] = %f\n", res[1]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

When I debug the program, it seems that all the `arg_values` are set correctly:

```
(gdb) p ((double *) arg_values[2])[0]
$1 = 99
(gdb) p ((double *) arg_values[2])[1]
$2 = 15
```

You can see above that the `arg_values` third values is correctly set to the `res` array.

However, when I am inside the function my_func, the third argument (the `res` array) becomes `NULL`:

```
Breakpoint 2, my_func (a=3, b=2, res=0x0) at test_ffi.c:6
6           res[0] = a + b;
```

I do not really understand what is wrong here. Could somebody explain to me, why this happens and how to fix it? Thank you!

**Update**

Thanks to the comments by @selbie, the following modified program works (note that we obtain a second pointer to the array `res` and pass its address to FFI):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ffi.h>

unsigned my_func(double a, double b, double *res) {
    res[0] = a + b;
    res[1] = a - b;

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ffi_cif cif;
    ffi_type *arg_types[3] = {
        &ffi_type_double,
        &ffi_type_double,
        &ffi_type_pointer
    };
    ffi_type *rettype = &ffi_type_uint;

    if (ffi_prep_cif(&cif, FFI_DEFAULT_ABI, 3, rettype, arg_types) != FFI_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ffi_prep_cif is not successful\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    double a = 3.0;
    double b = 2.0;
    double res[2] = {99.0, 15.0};
    double *p_res = res;
    void *arg_values[3] = {
        &a,
        &b,
        // res
        &p_res
    };

    unsigned status;
    ffi_call(&cif, FFI_FN(my_func), &status, arg_values);

    printf("Function return status code %u\n", status);
    printf("Values in res array: \n");
    printf("[0] = %f\n", res[0]);
    printf("[1] = %f\n", res[1]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that the same `&` operation must be used when passing functions as arguments. Although functions decay to pointers as arrays, here it is important to take the address of the function, because `libffi` requires a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this:

```
if (ffi_prep_cif(&cif, FFI_DEFAULT_ABI, 2, rettype, arg_types) != FFI_OK)
```

Be this:

```
if (ffi_prep_cif(&cif, FFI_DEFAULT_ABI, 3, rettype, arg_types) != FFI_OK)
```

Given that you are invoking a function that expects three parameters, but only initialized the ffi stuff to expect 2 parameters, it shouldn't be a surprised that one parameter goes missing.

Comment: Yes, thank you, you're right, silly mistake. However, now the arg_values look completely weird: `(gdb) p ((double *) arg_values)[0]
$2 = 6.9533558067599175e-310
(gdb) p ((double *) arg_values)[1]
$3 = 6.9533558067603127e-310
`

Comment: You might might need to Assign `double* ptr = res;` And then make `&ptr` the third argument to `arg_values`  Also, does ffi_call_prep need to know that the third argument is an array, not a pointer.

Comment: I am not sure why would I pass `&ptr`? `ptr` is already a pointer to double, and this is the third argument to the function `my_func`.

Comment: you're right, obtaining a second pointer (`ptr`) to the same array and passing `&ptr` works. I am not sure what is going on, as `res` and `ptr` are having the same value in the `main` function.

Comment: @DmitryKabanov - what you are you observing is a lesser-known subtlety of C/C++. And that is that a pointer to a local array is the array itself.  That is given `int array[N]`. Then **within the same scope**, `&array == array` as well as `&array == &array[0]`.   Since FFI wants a pointer to a pointer, we just save off the array address to an actual pointer instance and pass the pointer to that variable.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c

Comment: thank you very much for all the explanations. It seems like the equivalence of arrays and pointers is not what they usually say. I was reading this: https://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryvsadr.html and it says there that `&array` and `array` have different type (smalll experiment with `gcc` confirms that): `&array` is a pointer to array, while `array` is a pointer to the first element, and they are not the same, although the values are the same