# Why can't I just add an int to a memory address to address any array?

Tags: c, types, segmentation-fault, out-of-memory

I am trying to override part of my first string with my second one with an offset of 2.

Here is my second attempt that works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
   char s[] = "Hello, World!";
   char a[] = "aaa";

   printf("%d\n", &s);
   printf("%d\n", &s[2]);

   memcpy(&s[2], a, sizeof(a)-1);
   printf("%s\n", s);
   return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc -o test test2.c && ./test 
520783106
520783108
Heaaa, World!
```

And here is my first attempt, that does not work, raises a warning at compilation and segfaults:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
   char s[] = "Hello, World!";
   char a[] = "aaa";

   printf("%d\n", &s);
   printf("%d\n", sizeof(char)*2);
   printf("%d\n", &s + (sizeof(char)*2));

   memcpy(&s + (sizeof(char)*2), a, sizeof(a)-1);
   printf("%s\n", s);
   return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc -o test test1.c && ./test 
test1.c: In function ‘main’:
test1.c:12:4: warning: ‘memcpy’ writing 3 bytes into a region of size 0 overflows the destination [-Wstringop-overflow=]
   12 |    memcpy(&s + (sizeof(char)*2), a, sizeof(a)-1);
      |    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test1.c:5:9: note: at offset 28 into destination object ‘s’ of size 14
    5 |    char s[] = "Hello, World!";
      |         ^
1547566642
2
1547566670
Hello, World!
Segmentation fault
```

Can someone explain to me why test1 is not working ?

Why is the sum of 1547566642 and 2 equal 1547566670 and not 1547566644 ?

I assume it's a type problem. The return of sizeof is size_t but what is the type of &s ?

Thank you in advance for your help. ;)

Comment: Use `%p` to print a pointer, not `%d`.

Comment: [How come an array's address is equal to its value in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2528328/20785822) This answer should help you.

Comment: And use `%zu` to print the result of a `sizeof` operation.

Comment: Also, `sizeof(char)` is specified to *always* be equal to `1`.

Comment: TL;DR: The difference is because of types. `&s[2]` have the type `char *`. `&s` has the type `char (*)[14]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example has turned a bit complicated, likely by accident. The thing you need to focus on understanding is "array decay", which means that whenever an array is used in most expressions, it "decays" into a pointer to its first element.

For example in the expression `s[2]`, `s` decays to a pointer to `char`. The `[]` operator is defined to be 100% equivalent to pointer arithmetic, meaning that `s[2]` is identical to writing `*(s+2)` (but the former is best since it is more readable). In either case you end up dealing with a pointer and not an array.

Now there are some exceptions when array decay does not happen and you've encountered some of them here. When the address-of operator is used on array, decay does not happen. So `&s` does not give the address of the first element, but of the array itself. Although since both the array and its first element has the same address, you get the same address no matter if you print `&s` or `&s[0]`. But they are different types. `&s` gives a pointer to array of type `char (*)[14]` in this case, but `&s[0]` gives a plain `char*`.

Now these types matter when you start to do pointer arithmetic, because when doing that, the addition works on `sizeof(pointed-at-item)` basis. And so `&s + 2` gives an increase of 2*14 = 28 bytes, whereas `&s[0] + 2` gives an increase of 2 bytes. The former is obviously wrong here.

Another exception to the array decay is the `sizeof` operator - as you noticed, you can use it on arrays and get the array size in bytes. It wouldn't work on a decayed/pointed-at array, so if we do `char* ptr = s; ... sizeof(ptr)` we don't get the size of the array but the pointer itself, which isn't likely useful.

---

Other things of note:

- `sizeof(char)` is by definition guaranteed to always be `1` so there's no point of multiplying anything with `sizeof(char)` - it just adds clutter to the code.
- When printing addresses with `printf`, you are supposed to use `%p`. Partially because `%d` might not be large enough to correctly represent an address on the given system (it is not on x86_64 for example), partially because addresses are always written in hex and `%p` takes care of that. Pedantically, we should also cast the pointer to `(void*)`, so `printf("%p\n", (void*)&s[0]);` would be the most correct way to print the address of the first item.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the type of `s` is `char[14]`, not `char`. So `&s` is a pointer to `char[14]`, not a pointer to `char`. When you perform arithmetic on a pointer, it multiplies by the size of the type it points to. So `&s + 2` is not the same as `&s[2]`. The size of `char[14]` is `14`, so this adds 28 bytes to the pointer.

Change `&s +` to just `s +`. When you use an array name in this way, it automatically decayse to a pointer to the first element.

In general, `&array[index]` is equivalent to `array+index`.

Answer (score 1):

`s` is a `char[14]`. When taking its address you get a `char(*)[14]` and by adding `sizeof(char) * 2`, you step 2 `char[14]`s in memory. That is 28 bytes forward.

You should let `s` decay into a pointer (a `char*`) to the first element and *then* add 2:

```c
memcpy(s + 2, a, sizeof a - 1);
//     ^ 
//     not &s
```